# Global keyboard capture in C# application

Tags: .net, events, keyboard-hook

I want to capture a keyboard shortcut in my application and trigger a dialog to appear if the user presses a keyboard combo even outside of the app. Similar to Google Desktop Search's Ctrl, Ctrl to bring up the search dialog.

I have tried using some keyboard hook modules out there that basically use Win32 interop to get this effect but each implementation I've tried ties down the keyboard to some extent to where you start getting weird behaviors when the application is doing something intensive. Such as loading a large amount of data, this would cause the keyboard and mouse to lockup.

I'm looking for a lightweight solution that would allow this to be done without tying down the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: you could specify what modules you already tried.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81150/best-way-to-tackle-global-hotkey-processing-in-c/2611761#2611761

Comment: If you're still looking for an easy way to do this in 2022, I uploaded a nuget package that makes it quite easy to register such global hotkeys: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NonInvasiveKeyboardHookLibrary/

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Stephen Toub [wrote a great article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c) on implementing global keyboard hooks in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class InterceptKeys
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: How can I use this class?

Comment: Any reason why this would be returning odd characters?

Comment: @VAAA Add a class to your solution.  If you already have a main() in Program.cs, rename the main() in this class to InitializeComponent() and then call it in your project App() method eg. SysTrayApp().  See the linked article comments for more Q & A answered by Stephen.

Comment: This gives you the raw key that was pressed, like "S", but is there a way to determine what key would be inserted, for example if caps lock is off, then "s", but if it's on, then "S"?

Comment: I can't get this to work at all.. First of all it doesn't know what (Keys) is..  And even when I just try to console write the vkcode it found it never calls the HookCallback at all.

Comment: Its doesn't capture Alt (aka LMenu) down. Any ideas?

Comment: **How can I use this class?** Here is an example of how to wire it up and unhook it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10257266/495455

Answer (score 62):

Here's my code that works:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SnagFree.TrayApp.Core
{
    class GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs : HandledEventArgs
    {
        public GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState KeyboardState { get; private set; }
        public GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent KeyboardData { get; private set; }

        public GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(
            GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent keyboardData,
            GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState keyboardState)
        {
            KeyboardData = keyboardData;
            KeyboardState = keyboardState;
        }
    }

    //Based on https://gist.github.com/Stasonix
    class GlobalKeyboardHook : IDisposable
    {
        public event EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> KeyboardPressed;

        public GlobalKeyboardHook()
        {
            _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            _hookProc = LowLevelKeyboardProc; // we must keep alive _hookProc, because GC is not aware about SetWindowsHookEx behaviour.

            _user32LibraryHandle = LoadLibrary("User32");
            if (_user32LibraryHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to load library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }



            _windowsHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _hookProc, _user32LibraryHandle, 0);
            if (_windowsHookHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to adjust keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // because we can unhook only in the same thread, not in garbage collector thread
                if (_windowsHookHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    if (!UnhookWindowsHookEx(_windowsHookHandle))
                    {
                        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to remove keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
                    }
                    _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                    // ReSharper disable once DelegateSubtraction
                    _hookProc -= LowLevelKeyboardProc;
                }
            }

            if (_user32LibraryHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (!FreeLibrary(_user32LibraryHandle)) // reduces reference to library by 1.
                {
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to unload library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
                }
                _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        ~GlobalKeyboardHook()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private IntPtr _windowsHookHandle;
        private IntPtr _user32LibraryHandle;
        private HookProc _hookProc;

        delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

        /// <summary>
        /// The SetWindowsHookEx function installs an application-defined hook procedure into a hook chain.
        /// You would install a hook procedure to monitor the system for certain types of events. These events are
        /// associated either with a specific thread or with all threads in the same desktop as the calling thread.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">hook type</param>
        /// <param name="lpfn">hook procedure</param>
        /// <param name="hMod">handle to application instance</param>
        /// <param name="dwThreadId">thread identifier</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is the handle to the hook procedure.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

        /// <summary>
        /// The UnhookWindowsHookEx function removes a hook procedure installed in a hook chain by the SetWindowsHookEx function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hhk">handle to hook procedure</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is true.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);

        /// <summary>
        /// The CallNextHookEx function passes the hook information to the next hook procedure in the current hook chain.
        /// A hook procedure can call this function either before or after processing the hook information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHook">handle to current hook</param>
        /// <param name="code">hook code passed to hook procedure</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">value passed to hook procedure</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">value passed to hook procedure</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is true.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// A virtual-key code. The code must be a value in the range 1 to 254.
            /// </summary>
            public int VirtualCode;

            /// <summary>
            /// A hardware scan code for the key. 
            /// </summary>
            public int HardwareScanCode;

            /// <summary>
            /// The extended-key flag, event-injected Flags, context code, and transition-state flag. This member is specified as follows. An application can use the following values to test the keystroke Flags. Testing LLKHF_INJECTED (bit 4) will tell you whether the event was injected. If it was, then testing LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED (bit 1) will tell you whether or not the event was injected from a process running at lower integrity level.
            /// </summary>
            public int Flags;

            /// <summary>
            /// The time stamp stamp for this message, equivalent to what GetMessageTime would return for this message.
            /// </summary>
            public int TimeStamp;

            /// <summary>
            /// Additional information associated with the message. 
            /// </summary>
            public IntPtr AdditionalInformation;
        }

        public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        //const int HC_ACTION = 0;

        public enum KeyboardState
        {
            KeyDown = 0x0100,
            KeyUp = 0x0101,
            SysKeyDown = 0x0104,
            SysKeyUp = 0x0105
        }

        public const int VkSnapshot = 0x2c;
        //const int VkLwin = 0x5b;
        //const int VkRwin = 0x5c;
        //const int VkTab = 0x09;
        //const int VkEscape = 0x18;
        //const int VkControl = 0x11;
        const int KfAltdown = 0x2000;
        public const int LlkhfAltdown = (KfAltdown >> 8);

        public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            bool fEatKeyStroke = false;

            var wparamTyped = wParam.ToInt32();
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(KeyboardState), wparamTyped))
            {
                object o = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent));
                LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent p = (LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent)o;

                var eventArguments = new GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(p, (KeyboardState)wparamTyped);

                EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> handler = KeyboardPressed;
                handler?.Invoke(this, eventArguments);

                fEatKeyStroke = eventArguments.Handled;
            }

            return fEatKeyStroke ? (IntPtr)1 : CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SnagFree.TrayApp.Core
{
    internal class Controller : IDisposable
    {
        private GlobalKeyboardHook _globalKeyboardHook;

        public void SetupKeyboardHooks()
        {
            _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
            _globalKeyboardHook.KeyboardPressed += OnKeyPressed;
        }

        private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs e)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode);

            if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode != GlobalKeyboardHook.VkSnapshot)
                return;

            // seems, not needed in the life.
            //if (e.KeyboardState == GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState.SysKeyDown &&
            //    e.KeyboardData.Flags == GlobalKeyboardHook.LlkhfAltdown)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Alt + Print Screen");
            //    e.Handled = true;
            //}
            //else

            if (e.KeyboardState == GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState.KeyDown)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Print Screen");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _globalKeyboardHook?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Waw, this is awesome! You can even capture alt-F4 and prevent that the application would close. You even used C# 6.0 in your example :)

Comment: Thanks! I used this code and it works.But If I press the key after a while, there is an exception saying the delegate is garbage collected, and the managed code should keep it alive . then there is a null reference exception. can you help me with this ?

Comment: Hi @Golnar, I have this problem too. Make sure you have no static stuff around there, it is very dangerous in the context of garbage collection. Especially the event.

Comment: I would recommend adding `public Keys Key { get { return (Keys)VirtualCode; } }` to `LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent`. This takes the need to deal with the virtual codes which everyone has to google. **Also:** You can then change `VkSnapshot` from being an `int` to `Keys` and easely just place a Key. I went a step further and placed a `public static Keys[] RegisteredKeys`. OnPressed comes `if (!GlobalKeyboardHook.RegisteredKeys.Contains(e.KeyboardData.Key)) return;`. You could for sure just prevent the Event from being fired ;).

Comment: @C4d I think the community (at least I) would appreciate it when you post your solution too

Comment: @dube After 10 years? I'm not sure. But I get the point. After looking at my comment after a year that has passed it seems to be a bit too hard to follow. I'll set a reminder for today evening. Maybe I'll have some time to reconstruct it.

Comment: @C4d are you from the future? because your comment was from 2018, which is currently considered "last year" :-D

Comment: @dube hehe, this question is 10 years old. I've posted my modified version below. Have fun with it!

Comment: What is KfAltdown and LlkhfAltDown? I can expect what are them for, but I can't understand how it works. I don't know what prefix (e.g. Kf, Llkhf) mean and why I have shift the bits. I wanna understand this code for my study.

Answer (score 21):

As requested by [dube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304179/dube) I'm posting my modified version of [Siarhei Kuchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212746/siarhei-kuchuk)'s answer.
*If you want to check my changes search for `// EDT`. I've commented most of it.*

**The Setup**

```
class GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs : HandledEventArgs
{
    public GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState KeyboardState { get; private set; }
    public GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent KeyboardData { get; private set; }

    public GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(
        GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent keyboardData,
        GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState keyboardState)
    {
        KeyboardData = keyboardData;
        KeyboardState = keyboardState;
    }
}

//Based on https://gist.github.com/Stasonix
class GlobalKeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> KeyboardPressed;

    // EDT: Added an optional parameter (registeredKeys) that accepts keys to restict
    // the logging mechanism.
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="registeredKeys">Keys that should trigger logging. Pass null for full logging.</param>
    public GlobalKeyboardHook(Keys[] registeredKeys = null)
    {
        RegisteredKeys = registeredKeys;
        _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        _hookProc = LowLevelKeyboardProc; // we must keep alive _hookProc, because GC is not aware about SetWindowsHookEx behaviour.

        _user32LibraryHandle = LoadLibrary("User32");
        if (_user32LibraryHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to load library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
        }



        _windowsHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _hookProc, _user32LibraryHandle, 0);
        if (_windowsHookHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to adjust keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // because we can unhook only in the same thread, not in garbage collector thread
            if (_windowsHookHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (!UnhookWindowsHookEx(_windowsHookHandle))
                {
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to remove keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
                }
                _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                // ReSharper disable once DelegateSubtraction
                _hookProc -= LowLevelKeyboardProc;
            }
        }

        if (_user32LibraryHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (!FreeLibrary(_user32LibraryHandle)) // reduces reference to library by 1.
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to unload library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }
            _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    ~GlobalKeyboardHook()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private IntPtr _windowsHookHandle;
    private IntPtr _user32LibraryHandle;
    private HookProc _hookProc;

    delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    /// <summary>
    /// The SetWindowsHookEx function installs an application-defined hook procedure into a hook chain.
    /// You would install a hook procedure to monitor the system for certain types of events. These events are
    /// associated either with a specific thread or with all threads in the same desktop as the calling thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="idHook">hook type</param>
    /// <param name="lpfn">hook procedure</param>
    /// <param name="hMod">handle to application instance</param>
    /// <param name="dwThreadId">thread identifier</param>
    /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is the handle to the hook procedure.</returns>
    [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

    /// <summary>
    /// The UnhookWindowsHookEx function removes a hook procedure installed in a hook chain by the SetWindowsHookEx function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hhk">handle to hook procedure</param>
    /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is true.</returns>
    [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);

    /// <summary>
    /// The CallNextHookEx function passes the hook information to the next hook procedure in the current hook chain.
    /// A hook procedure can call this function either before or after processing the hook information.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hHook">handle to current hook</param>
    /// <param name="code">hook code passed to hook procedure</param>
    /// <param name="wParam">value passed to hook procedure</param>
    /// <param name="lParam">value passed to hook procedure</param>
    /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is true.</returns>
    [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A virtual-key code. The code must be a value in the range 1 to 254.
        /// </summary>
        public int VirtualCode;

        // EDT: added a conversion from VirtualCode to Keys.
        /// <summary>
        /// The VirtualCode converted to typeof(Keys) for higher usability.
        /// </summary>
        public Keys Key { get { return (Keys)VirtualCode; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// A hardware scan code for the key. 
        /// </summary>
        public int HardwareScanCode;

        /// <summary>
        /// The extended-key flag, event-injected Flags, context code, and transition-state flag. This member is specified as follows. An application can use the following values to test the keystroke Flags. Testing LLKHF_INJECTED (bit 4) will tell you whether the event was injected. If it was, then testing LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED (bit 1) will tell you whether or not the event was injected from a process running at lower integrity level.
        /// </summary>
        public int Flags;

        /// <summary>
        /// The time stamp stamp for this message, equivalent to what GetMessageTime would return for this message.
        /// </summary>
        public int TimeStamp;

        /// <summary>
        /// Additional information associated with the message. 
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr AdditionalInformation;
    }

    public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    //const int HC_ACTION = 0;

    public enum KeyboardState
    {
        KeyDown = 0x0100,
        KeyUp = 0x0101,
        SysKeyDown = 0x0104,
        SysKeyUp = 0x0105
    }

    // EDT: Replaced VkSnapshot(int) with RegisteredKeys(Keys[])
    public static Keys[] RegisteredKeys;
    const int KfAltdown = 0x2000;
    public const int LlkhfAltdown = (KfAltdown >> 8);

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        bool fEatKeyStroke = false;

        var wparamTyped = wParam.ToInt32();
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(KeyboardState), wparamTyped))
        {
            object o = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent));
            LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent p = (LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent)o;

            var eventArguments = new GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(p, (KeyboardState)wparamTyped);

            // EDT: Removed the comparison-logic from the usage-area so the user does not need to mess around with it.
            // Either the incoming key has to be part of RegisteredKeys (see constructor on top) or RegisterdKeys
            // has to be null for the event to get fired.
            var key = (Keys)p.VirtualCode;
            if (RegisteredKeys == null || RegisteredKeys.Contains(key))
            {
                EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> handler = KeyboardPressed;
                handler?.Invoke(this, eventArguments);

                fEatKeyStroke = eventArguments.Handled;
            }
        }

        return fEatKeyStroke ? (IntPtr)1 : CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

**The Usage** *differences can be seen here*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private GlobalKeyboardHook _globalKeyboardHook;

    private void buttonHook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hooks only into specified Keys (here "A" and "B").
        _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook(new Keys[] { Keys.A, Keys.B });

        // Hooks into all keys.
        _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
        _globalKeyboardHook.KeyboardPressed += OnKeyPressed;
    }

    private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs e)
    {
        // EDT: No need to filter for VkSnapshot anymore. This now gets handled
        // through the constructor of GlobalKeyboardHook(...).
        if (e.KeyboardState == GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState.KeyDown)
        {
            // Now you can access both, the key and virtual code
            Keys loggedKey = e.KeyboardData.Key;
            int loggedVkCode = e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Siarhei Kuchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212746/siarhei-kuchuk) for his post. Even tho I've simplified the usage this initial code was very useful for me.

Comment: Had some problems with the code.  First off, because it's the last version to have an XNA wrapper and I have some old 3D software I wrote, I still use VS2012 for some things including this.  The C#6 operators replaced I sat about to try it.

Comment: It did not work but I needed it in VS2012 so that may be an issue.  I suppose the problem I found is true in C#6 also.

The GlobalKeyboardHook constructor (above) begins with:

RegisteredKeys = registeredKeys;

Unfortunately registeredKeys does not persist and therefore the pointer to it becomes invalid on return and is null on all calls thereafter.  My fix was to check it for null on the way in, create an equal sized array in the constructor (static and persistent) and copy the passed array data into it).

Thanks very much regardless.  Duly appreciated!

Comment: This seems to fail after a number of keypresses?

Managed Debugging Assistant 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' 
  Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' : 'A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'Keyboard!Keyboard.GlobalKeyboardHook+HookProc::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.'

Comment: @C4d The hotkey is captured but I'm receiving the following error immedaitely after I display a `MessageBox` (to validate the handler is active and working): `Managed Debugging Assistant 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' : 'A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'GlobalKeyboardHook+HookProc::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.'` How can I resolve this exception?

Comment: ^ The above exception occurs on the following line at the bottom of `LowLeveKeyboardProc()`: `return fEatKeyStroke ? (IntPtr)1 : CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);`

Comment: I currently havent got the environment to test this. I'll keep this in mind and check it out as soon as I will be able to.

Comment: @Chad I got that too, in my case the GlobalKeyboardHook class was not being disposed and after some time led to the exception.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you! However, I have a question: is it possible to check for multiple keys (eg. CTRL + F1) in that `OnKeyPressed` method?

Comment: @3AgL3DeeJay Yes it is. Within `OnKeyPressed` you have `e.KeyboardData.Key` and `e.KeyboardState` (keyDown/keyUp). If its ctrl, save the keyboardState to a global variable. If the next key comes in, you can check your global state if ctrl is currently down or not.

Answer (score 12):

If a global hotkey would suffice, then [RegisterHotKey](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html) would do the trick

Answer (score 1):

For system global key combinations and multi-key short-keys there is very easy one [here](https://gist.github.com/dudikeleti/a0ce3044b683634793cf297addbf5f11). Class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;



namespace KeyboardUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provide a way to handle a global keyboard hooks
    /// <remarks>This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. 
    /// The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook.
    /// Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.</remarks>
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class GlobalKeyboardHook : IDisposable
    {
        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        private LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc;
        private readonly IntPtr _hookId = IntPtr.Zero;
        private static GlobalKeyboardHook _instance;
        private Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<KeyCombination, HookActions>> _hookEvents;
        private bool _disposed;
        private KeyCombination _pressedKeys;

        /// <summary>
        /// Return a singleton instance of <see cref="GlobalKeyboardHook"/>
        /// </summary>
        public static GlobalKeyboardHook Instance
        {
            get
            {
   
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _instance, new GlobalKeyboardHook(), null);
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        private GlobalKeyboardHook()
        {
            _proc = HookCallback;
            _hookEvents = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<KeyCombination, HookActions>>();
            _hookId = SetHook(_proc);
            _pressedKeys = new KeyCombination();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Register a keyboard hook event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="keys">The short keys. minimum is two keys</param>
        /// <param name="execute">The action to run when the key ocmbination has pressed</param>
        /// <param name="message">Empty if no error occurred otherwise error message</param>
        /// <param name="runAsync">True if the action should execute in the background. -Be careful from thread affinity- Default is false</param>
        /// <param name="dispose">An action to run when unsubscribing from keyboard hook. can be null</param>
        /// <returns>Event id to use when unregister</returns>
        public int Hook(List<Key> keys, Action execute, out string message, bool runAsync = false, Action<object> dispose = null)
        {
            if (_hookEvents == null)
            {
                message = "Can't register";
                return -1;
            }

            if (keys == null || execute == null)
            {
                message = "'keys' and 'execute' can't be null";
                return -1;
            }

            if (keys.Count < 2)
            {
                message = "You must provide at least two keys";
                return -1;
            }

            if (!ValidateKeys(keys))
            {
                message = "Unallowed key. Only 'shift', 'ctrl' and 'a' - 'z' are allowed";
                return -1;
            }

            var kc = new KeyCombination(keys);
            int id = kc.GetHashCode();
            if (_hookEvents.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                message = "The key combination is already exist it the application";
                return -1;
            }

            // if the action should run async, wrap it with Task
            Action asyncAction = null;
            if (runAsync)
                asyncAction = () => Task.Run(() => execute);

            _hookEvents[id] = new KeyValuePair<KeyCombination, HookActions>(kc, new HookActions(asyncAction ?? execute, dispose));
            message = string.Empty;
            return id;
        }

        private bool ValidateKeys(IEnumerable<Key> keys)
        {
            return keys.All(t => IsKeyValid((int)t));
        }

        private bool IsKeyValid(int key)
        {
            // 'alt' is sys key and hence is disallowed.
            // a - z and shift, ctrl. 
            return key >= 44 && key <= 69 || key >= 116 && key <= 119;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Un register a keyboard hook event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">event id to remove</param>
        /// <param name="obj">parameter to pass to dispose method</param>
        public void UnHook(int id, object obj = null)
        {
            if (_hookEvents == null || id < 0 || !_hookEvents.ContainsKey(id)) return;

            var hook = _hookEvents[id];

            if (hook.Value != null && hook.Value.Dispose != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    hook.Value.Dispose(obj);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // need to be define if we need to throw the exception
                }
            }

            _hookEvents.Remove(id);
        }

        private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode < 0)
                return CallNextHookEx(_hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);

            var result = new IntPtr(0);
            if (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                _pressedKeys.Add(KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam))); // vkCode (in KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) is DWORD (actually it can be 0-254)
                if (_pressedKeys.Count >= 2)
                {
                    var keysToAction = _hookEvents.Values.FirstOrDefault(val => val.Key.Equals(_pressedKeys));
                    if (keysToAction.Value != null)
                    {
                        keysToAction.Value.Execute();
                        // don't try to get the action again after the execute because it may removed already
                        result = new IntPtr(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
            {
                _pressedKeys.Clear();
            }

            // in case we processed the message, prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain
            // return result.ToInt32() == 0 ? CallNextHookEx(_hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam) : result;
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        #region extern
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        #endregion

        #region IDsiposable
        private void Dispose(bool dispose)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_disposed)
                    return;

                UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookId);
                if (dispose)
                {
                    _proc = null;
                    _hookEvents = null;
                    _pressedKeys = null;
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                }
                _disposed = true;
            }
            // ReSharper disable once EmptyGeneralCatchClause
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        ~GlobalKeyboardHook()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
        #endregion

        private class HookActions
        {
            public HookActions(Action excetue, Action<object> dispose = null)
            {
                Exceute = excetue;
                Dispose = dispose;
            }

            public Action Exceute { get; set; }
            public Action<object> Dispose { get; set; }

        }
        private class KeyCombination : IEquatable<KeyCombination>
        {
            private readonly bool _canModify;
            public KeyCombination(List<Key> keys)
            {
                _keys = keys ?? new List<Key>();
            }

            public KeyCombination()
            {
                _keys = new List<Key>();
                _canModify = true;
            }

            public void Add(Key key)
            {
                if (_canModify)
                {
                    _keys.Add(key);
                }
            }

            public void Remove(Key key)
            {
                if (_canModify)
                {
                    _keys.Remove(key);
                }
            }

            public void Clear()
            {
                if (_canModify)
                {
                    _keys.Clear();
                }
            }

            public int Count { get { return _keys.Count; } }

            private readonly List<Key> _keys;

            public bool Equals(KeyCombination other)
            {
                return other._keys != null && _keys != null && KeysEqual(other._keys);
            }

            private bool KeysEqual(List<Key> keys)
            {
                if (keys == null || _keys == null || keys.Count != _keys.Count) return false;
                for (int i = 0; i < _keys.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (_keys[i] != keys[i])
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (obj is KeyCombination)
                    return Equals((KeyCombination)obj);
                return false;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                if (_keys == null) return 0;

                //http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416
                //http://stackoverflow.com/a/8094931
                //assume keys not going to modify after we use GetHashCode
                unchecked
                {
                    int hash = 19;
                    for (int i = 0; i < _keys.Count; i++)
                    {
                        hash = hash * 31 + _keys[i].GetHashCode();
                    }
                    return hash;
                }
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                if (_keys == null)
                    return string.Empty;

                var sb = new StringBuilder((_keys.Count - 1) * 4 + 10);
                for (int i = 0; i < _keys.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i < _keys.Count - 1)
                        sb.Append(_keys[i] + " , ");
                    else
                        sb.Append(_keys[i]);
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And how to use it in form application:

```
string message;
var hookId = GlobalKeyboardHook.Instance.Hook(
    new List<System.Windows.Input.Key> {
        System.Windows.Input.Key.A,
        System.Windows.Input.Key.B
    },
    () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a-b");
    },
    out message);
```

And very simple example for console application:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    string message;
    var hookId = GlobalKeyboardHook.Instance.Hook(
        new List<System.Windows.Input.Key> {
            System.Windows.Input.Key.A,
            System.Windows.Input.Key.B
        },
        () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a-b");
        },
        out message);
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    Application.Run();
    GlobalKeyboardHook.Instance.UnHook(hookId);
}
```

I also recommend to read this post :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46014022/4238323

**Important Note:**
System wide hooks are extremely dangerous you MUST be very careful about what are you doing. If you hook key event using this method make sure unhook and release memory correctly which It could be hard specially in console application. I encountered several Blue-Pages and some system instability such as shutdown and sleep problems and freeze-up after some hours of using this. So please take extra care while using it.

Comment: I fixed some misspellings in this post. There was one in code, `Exceute()` - please check it is all correct.

Answer (score 0):

My rep is too low to comment, but concerning the `CallbackOnCollectedDelegate` exception, I modified the `public void SetupKeyboardHooks()` in ***C4d's*** answer to look like this:

```
public void SetupKeyboardHooks(out object hookProc)
{
  _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
  _globalKeyboardHook.KeyboardPressed += OnKeyPressed;


  hookProc = _globalKeyboardHook.GcSafeHookProc;
}
```

where `GcSafeHookProc` is just a public getter for `_hookProc` in OPs

```
_hookProc = LowLevelKeyboardProc; // we must keep alive _hookProc, because GC is not aware about SetWindowsHookEx behaviour.
```

and stored the `hookProc` as a private field in the class calling the `SetupKeyboardHooks(...)`, therefore keeping the reference alive, save from garbage collection, no more `CallbackOnCollectedDelegate` exception. Seems having this additional reference in the `GlobalKeyboardHook` class is not sufficient. Maybe make sure that this reference is also disposed when closing your app.

Answer (score -3):

```
private void buttonHook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Hooks only into specified Keys (here "A" and "B").
    // (***) Use this constructor

    _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook(new Keys[] { Keys.A, Keys.B });

    // Hooks into all keys.
    // (***) Or this - not both

    _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
    _globalKeyboardHook.KeyboardPressed += OnKeyPressed;
}
```

And then is working fine.