# Global Keyboard Hooks (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, hotkeys, global-hotkey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-application)

Can anyone help me setup a global keyboard hook for my application?

I want to set hotkeys (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) that can be used when not focused on the actual form.

Answer (score 7):

Paul's post links to two answers, one telling you how to implement a hook, and another telling you to call RegisterHotKey. You shouldn't need to install a hook for something as simple as a Ctrl+S hotkey, so call [RegisterHotKey](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use C#'s MessageFilter. It should work while any control/form from your application's process has focus.

Sample Code:

```
class KeyboardMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == ((int)Helper.WindowsMessages.WM_KEYDOWN))
        {
            switch ((int)m.WParam)
            {
                case (int)Keys.Escape:
                    // Do Something
                    return true;
                case (int)Keys.Right:
                    // Do Something
                    return true;
                case (int)Keys.Left:
                    // Do Something
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And than simply add a new MessageFilter to your Application:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new KeyboardMessageFilter());
```

Comment: +1 for the cleanest solution, which is also good for mouse events. Thanks!

Comment: what's `Helper` do? and how do i import it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953297/the-name-helper-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context