# Capturing out of focus keyboard input C# console program

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, console

I've been trying to use the Windows.Input.Keyboard namespace in the .NET framework to **capture input from the keyboard when my program doesn't have focus**, but when I compile and debug it, an InvalidOperationException is thrown and tells me "**The calling thread must be STA**" when I try to check the pressed state of a key.
Now I don't know much about this threading business, but I can only assume that a console program can't run as an STA thread in which case does this mean I have to make a Forms or some other type of application other than a console program? Or is there a more friendly way to do it through a console program in a different .NET Framework namespace that I haven't heard about?

**tl;dr** How can I get keypresses that happen when my console program that's recording them isn't in focus?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to mark as duplicated but this guy:

[How can I make my Windows Forms application 'listen' for global key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726389/how-can-i-make-my-windows-forms-application-listen-for-global-key-presses)

answered that question before ;)
Use first Global Hook for c#. Works wery well for me