# How can I detect a hidden Desktop?

Tags: c#, wpf

There are a lot of shortcuts defined by Windows ([see here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts)), including the combination WIN+D to "*Display and hide the Desktop*".

I am working on an application developed with C# and WPF and I have to react on hiding the Desktop, e.g. the user pressed WIN+D.

I tried several approaches so far. First, I registered to the [Control.VisibleChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged?view=netframework-4.8) and [Window.StateChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.statechanged?view=netframework-4.8) events. Unfortunately, hiding the Desktop does not trigger one of them, i.e. the window of my application is neither minimized nor invisible when the Desktop is hidden.

Next, I tried hooking my own application to get more information. I used [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) for this. I got tons of events for all kind of situations, but nothing that said "Hey, your Desktop is now hidden". I was hoping to get an [EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/event-constants) for my main window or something like [EVENT_OBJECT_CLOAKED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/event-constants) or [EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/event-constants).

I am running out of ideas. Do you know any way to get notified when the Desktop is hidden (e.g. by pressing WIN+D)?

Comment: Related [How can I make my Windows Forms application 'listen' for global key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726389/how-can-i-make-my-windows-forms-application-listen-for-global-key-presses)

Comment: I was thinking about it. However, I would prefer reacting the event itself which is a much cleaner approach, because I would also be able react on the event when it's caused by any other source than a shortcut.

Comment: I would definitely NOT hook into WIN+D, because you can not only hide the Desktop with the keyboard shortcut, I would try to focus in WinEvents

Comment: Win10 & 7 - A `Window_StateChanged` handler fires for me with `this.WindowState` being `Minimized` when I hit Ctrl+D or use the "Show Desktop" taskbar gutter ...

Comment: You want to get notice when your app is being hidden, I wonder if `Win+D` causes `EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART` or `Alt+Tab` causes `EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW`. Edit: This is very similar to Alex's comment

Comment: That is strange, @AlexK. I added the Code below to my main window's constructor. I only the the window state Change, when I manually minimize/restore the window.

`StateChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}.RahmenView -> StateChanged - WindowState = {1}", this, WindowState);
            };

            IsVisibleChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}.RahmenView -> IsVisibleChanged - Visibility = {1}", this, Visibility);
            };`

Comment: Odd, I see `WpfApp1.MainWindow.RahmenView -> StateChanged - WindowState = Minimized` as expected on ctrl+D (V 4.7.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone someone faces the same issue, I found the solution to my problem. When you have set the property `ResizeMode` to `NoResize`, you won't get `WindowState` property updates when pressing WIN+D to minimize/bring back your Desktop. I could remove it from our source code because it was a relic from an early stage of the application.