# The name 'Helper' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, syntax-error

In my C# application, I am using a MessageFilter for a global key hook [as suggested by T Perquin.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/824478/5001439)

This is my current code:

```
 class KeyboardMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == ((int)Helper.WindowsMessages.WM_KEYDOWN))
        {
            switch ((int)m.WParam)
            {
                case (int)Keys.Escape:
                    // Do Something
                    return true;
                case (int)Keys.Right:
                    // Do Something
                    return true;
                case (int)Keys.Left:
                    // Do Something
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile and run (*to make sure the syntax's are correct*), I get this error: 
`The name 'Helper' does not exist in the current context`.

**What exactly is 'Helper' and how do I fix this error?**

Comment: `Helper` appears to be a namespace where constants for certain Windows messages are defined. With such a generic name it is unlikely to be a standard module - you will have to create your own, or just declare WM_KEYDOWN locally, if that's all you need.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I would like to use a global hook so that my application can use shortcuts when minimized. How would I go about using this code (If it's even possible) for a global hook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `Helper` is a class that contains static or constant variables like the Windows Message `WM_KEYDOWN`. Since you are only using that you can add it in your file.

```
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
```

Here are the other [Keyboard Input Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468861(v=vs.85).aspx), in case you need it.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked great for me. I will accept this answer once the option is available. :)