# C # Register function using Windows API to call back whenever key is pressed

Tags: c#, winapi

How can I use Windows API in C# to register a call back function to be called whenever key is pressed?

Comment: WinForms, WebForms, MVC, WPF, Console or global hook?

Comment: More information please. e.g. do you want a global hook?

Answer (score 3):

A simple google search brings up this promising solution:
[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

and even a search here on StackOverflow brings you (beside many others) to:
[Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application) which leads to [Low-Level Keyboard Hook in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c).

So where was the big problem in searching this on yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have noticed that some users think it is easier to ask then find out for themselves. It is does not take much to do a Google search. I try to avoid answering some StackOverflow questions where the poster hasn't provided sufficient information (i.e., what have they tried to do).