# Implementing timer states(Available,Busy,Away etc) in a chat application vb8

Tags: vb.net, implementation

I am currently developing a chat application and am trying to include:

- Various states, like MSN does, available, busy and away.
- If the user doesn't touch the keyboard for one minute, the state of the user isto be changed into Away.
  Or something similar to these.

I also need the program to be able to play a sound while running.

Can the community aid me with resources to help me implement this and perhaps any code if anyone has experience with a similar application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manage an inactive state, what you can do is use a timer paired with a [global keyboard hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-application) (the article is for C#, but you can easily translate it to VB.NET). Each time your application receives a keyboard message, the timer will be reset to the inactivity interval. If the timer runs out, you can set the status of your application to be inactive.