# How do I make structural equality to work on collection properties in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

One of the great advantages is supposed to be value based/structural equality, but how do I get that to work with collection properties?

Concrete simple example:

```
public record Something(string Id);
public record Sample(List<Something> something);
```

With the above records I would expect the following test to pass:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var x = new Sample(new List<Something>() {
            new Something("x1")
        });
        var y = new Sample(new List<Something>() {
            new Something("x1")
        });
        Assert.Equal(x, y);
    }
```

I understand that it is because of `List` being a reference type, but does it exist a collection that implements value based comparison? Basically I would like to do a "deep" value based comparison.

Comment: I guess I could convert it to json and compare the json, but that doesn't seems like an optimal solution to the problem.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63813872/2501279).

Comment: Thanks  @GuruStron, so it seems the answer is no... it doesn't exist. That's a shame. I've been in F# land for too long and there we get spoiled of it out of the box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [record types with collection properties & collections with value semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63813872/record-types-with-collection-properties-collections-with-value-semantics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records don't do this automatically, but you can implement the `Equals` method yourself:

```cs
public record Sample(List<Something> something) : IEquatable<Sample>
{
    public virtual bool Equals(Sample? other) => 
        other != null &&
        Enumerable.SequenceEqual(something, other.something);
}
```

But note that `GetHashCode` should be overridden to be consistent with `Equals`. See also [implement GetHashCode() for objects that contain collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567450/implement-gethashcode-for-objects-that-contain-collections)