# How can I convert List<object> to unique id

Tags: c#, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good GetHashCode() override for List of Foo objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094867/good-gethashcode-override-for-list-of-foo-objects)

I have `List` of `Objects`, Object has ID, FileName, Status(Enumerator), DateStamp, UserId.
Using `Linq` I filter `List` using `UserId` and send it to Web App.

I need to get some kind of `Unique Id` for filtered result and compare it next time to detect changes for current user. If new Object added for current user or property of existing object is changed `Unique Id` should be different.

I have tried to use code below to get Hash Code but hash code is different for every myList object even objects and object properties are the same. Any ideas please?

```
myList= _queueList.GetItems(p => p.User.Id == userId)
                  .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateStamp)
                  .ToList();

myList.GetHashCode()
```

Comment: @DanielA.White that doesn't matter for this usage -- the only requirement is that if the data changes the id changes.  The chance of the data changing but the hash remaining the same by accident is vanishingly small.  A good hash should be acceptable for this use.

Comment: @karaken12 the point is that's not what GetHashCode() is used for.  I would be suprised if List<T> provided an implementation other than the base Object.GetHashCode(), which isn't going to tell you anything about the uniqueness of the contents.

Comment: @drch Isn't that exactly what [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) is for? "A hash function must have the following properties: If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value." -- If you want two lists to be equal if they contain "equal" objects, this seems entirely appropriate.  See the question linked to by Hans.

Comment: @karaken12 a list's hash code isn't based on its contents.  If you're trying to see if a list of objects has changed, GetHashCode() won't help you.  See http://pastebin.com/qzskbaFR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage builtin cryptography like this:

```
string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(
    new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            string.Join(":", myList.Select(obj => obj.Id.ToString()).ToArray()
        )));
```

I put `Convert.ToBase64String()` to make it web-friendly (beware: the resulting string might become quite long if you have many records!)

Answer (score 1):

```
var uniqueId = string.Join(",", myList.Select(x=>x.Id.ToString()).ToArray());
```

If the string is very long, you could generate an md5 or sha1 and return that instead.