# Finding differences between two Lists with a Type properties as List C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, collections

I am trying to find difference between two lists and output them to a popup. But somehow i am not getting the correct difference between them using Except Methods. Please help to guide the best way to implement this

Here are the class details

```
public  class UserDetails

{

    public List<string> ManagementCenter;
    public List<string> Group;
    public List<string> Roles;
}
   List<UserDetails> userDetailsListFirst = new List<UserDetails>();
   List<UserDetails> userDetailsListSecond = new List<UserDetails>();

    //This is not working
   var valuesDifference =  userDetailsListSecond.Except(userDetailsListFirst);


  Expected Data
  -------------
  List A-
  Management Center: JP
  Application Group(s): Corporate   
  User Role(s): SuperRole; 

   List B-
   Management Center: JP
   Application Group(s): Corporate; Trading;Supplementary; 
   User Role(s): SuperRole; 

   Here Comparing List A with List B . and output should show missing one

   Management Center: JP
   Application Group(s):  Trading;Supplementary; 
   User Role(s): SuperRole;
```

Comment: try to override equals in your UserDetails class...

Comment: If your class does not override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` properly only the references are compared by default, not the properties. That's why `Enumerable.Except` does not work as expected. So either override them or provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<UserDetails>` for `Except`(or other LINQ methods). [Here's a possible implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8094931/284240) for `GetHashCode` if you want to compare list properties.

Comment: What you need is some custom difference. The methods that test equality only test that - whether two objects are equal or not. While you're able to provide some custom code to determine the equality itself, there's nothing out of the box that would provide such level of difference matching.

Comment: Have tried implementing the same, but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this example is truly representative of what you are trying to do, you can implement the Equals override and the GetHashCode override based on the fact that you are actually looking at sets of strings.  In the code below, I create a long string from the ManagementCenter, Group, and Roles lists and use that to compare equality and to create the hash code.

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public List<string> ManagementCenter;
    public List<string> Group;
    public List<string> Roles;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is UserDetails)
        {
            var otherUserDetail = obj as UserDetails;
            return string.Equals(GetTestValue(this), GetTestValue(otherUserDetail));
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static string GetTestValue(UserDetails userDetail)
    {
        return string.Join(";", userDetail.ManagementCenter) + "|" + string.Join(";", userDetail.Group) + "|" + string.Join(";", userDetail.Roles);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetTestValue(this).GetHashCode();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var a1 = new UserDetails
    {
        ManagementCenter = new List<string> { "JP" },
        Group = new List<string> { "Corporate" },
        Roles = new List<string> { "SuperRole" }
    };

    var a2 = new UserDetails  // same info, different object,
                              // should still be equal using
                              // our override of the equals method
    {
        ManagementCenter = new List<string> { "JP" },
        Group = new List<string> { "Corporate" },
        Roles = new List<string> { "SuperRole" }
    };

    var b = new UserDetails // different info, should not be equal
    {
        ManagementCenter = new List<string> { "JP" },
        Group = new List<string> { "Corporate", "Trading", "Supplementary" },
        Roles = new List<string> { "SuperRole" }
    };

    List<UserDetails> userDetailsListFirst = new List<UserDetails>();
    userDetailsListFirst.Add(a1);

    List<UserDetails> userDetailsListSecond = new List<UserDetails>();
    userDetailsListSecond.Add(a2);
    userDetailsListSecond.Add(b);

    //This is now working
    var valuesDifference = userDetailsListSecond.Except(userDetailsListFirst);
}
```

Comment: i tired implementing the same, but it seems i am not getting the expected output. :(

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `.Except` to lists of `UserDetails`. But you expect to get difference of `Group` lists, which is property of `UserDetails`. For your example where each of your lists contain only one `UserDetail` instance you can do something like this:

```
UserDetail first = userDetailsListFirst[0];
UserDetail second = userDetailsListSecond[0];
UserDetail result;
result.ManagementCenter = second.ManagementCenter;
result.Role = second.Role;
result.Group = second.Group.Except(first.Group).ToList();
```