# Distinct List<List<int>>?

Tags: c#, list, distinct

I have a problem with getting only the distinct lists. 
So I have :

```
List<List<int>> combinations = new List<List<int>>();
combinations.Add(new List<int> {1,1});
combinations.Add(new List<int> {1,2});
combinations.Add(new List<int> {1,1}); // Same
combinations.Add(new List<int> {1,3});
```

What I need to do is to get only :

```
{1,1}
{1,2}
{1,3}
```

I tried with this : `combinations = combinations.Distinct().ToList();`
But it does not work. 
Any ideas. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use your own comparer:

```
var distincts = 
    combinations
    .Distinct(new ListOfIntComparer());    

class ListOfIntComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        return
            a.SequenceEqual(b);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<int> l)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 19;
            foreach (var foo in l)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + foo.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
         }
    }
}
```

`GetHasCode()` implementation from Jon Skeet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094867/good-gethashcode-override-for-list-of-foo-objects-respecting-the-order).

Comment: It's worth noting that `GetHashCode()` only has to ensure that if two objects are equal then they have the same hash code and not the other way round. So an implementation as simple as `return l.Count;` could be sufficient, and might be more performant if you have long lists of varying lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to come up with the shortest oneliner. This is what i come up with.
Hope it helps you.

```
var unique = combinations.GroupBy(x => string.Join(",", x), (g, items) => items.First());
```

Answer (score -6):

Try adding a regular int array:

```
List<List<int>> lli = new List<List<int>>();

lli.Add((new int[] { 2, 4 }).ToList<int>());
```

Comment: try providing reason for suggestion.