# Return objects which contain Lists, based on the those lists matching

Tags: c#, linq

I have `Cell` objects which contain a `List<int>` called `PossibleValues`. I'm trying to find a way to get a list of cells in which all members have matching PossibleValues. I currently have:

```
foreach (var cell in group)
{
    var cellsWithMatchingPossibleValues = group.Where(c => c.PossibleValues == cell.PossibleValues);
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't working, I suspect my linq statement isn't comparing the contents of PossibleValues, but instead comparing a reference of some kind, so that even in the case where both lists are composed of 3 and nothing else, cellsWithMatchingPossibleValues ends up only containing one cell, although I'm not certain, or sure how to get around that.

To formalise the question:
**How can I return objects which contain Lists based on the those lists matching?**

Comment: group in foreach and group inside foreach is different, isn't it?

Comment: .ToList();  add this at the end of LINQ statement

Comment: Valentin:
Same group, I'm looking to find how many Cells within that group have matching PossibleValues lists, to do that I planned to loop through each cell and match that list against the lists of the whole group. 

I'd expect to always get 1 match with this, seeing as the cell is in the group.

If you have a more efficient idea, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: CodeConstruct: The issue isn't solved by doing a .ToList(); The resulting list still only contains one object when we would expect two.

Comment: Please let me know if I'm missing something, but wouldn't the GroupBy function be more what you're looking for here?  Also, doesn't this code re-initialize cellsWithMatchingPossibleValues with every iteration, basically removing whatever value was there before?

Comment: What is `PossibleValues`? Is it a list of strings, ints, or objects? Your answer to this question will make a **huge** difference in whether the answer is facile or complex.

Comment: Second question: are you iterating a collection of `Cell` objects and distilling a list of `Cell` objects having a common set of `PossibleValue`s, or do you have a single `Cell` object and trying to see which `Cell`s in a list match to it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "matching"? Same elements? Same elements in the same order?

Comment: Valid questions: PossibleValues is a list of ints.
Group is a List<Cell>.
Each Cell has a PossibleValues List<int>.

I'll be updating the main question to improve it in light of some of the questions I've had.

Comment: Bobson: Matching just means same elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `IEqualityComparer` interface and use `GroupBy` method.
Here you can find good [GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094867/good-gethashcode-override-for-list-of-foo-objects-respecting-the-order) for List, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order) how to compare a lists.

```
    public class PossibleValuesCellComparer : IEqualityComparer<Cell>
    {
        public bool Equals(Cell x, Cell y)
        {
            return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x.PossibleValues.OrderBy(t => t), y.PossibleValues.OrderBy(t => t));
        }


        public int GetHashCode(Cell cell)
        {
            var list = cell.PossibleValues.OrderBy(t => t);
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 19;
                foreach (var obj in list)
                {
                    hash = hash * 31 + obj.GetHashCode();
                }
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }

     ....

     var g2 = group.GroupBy(x => x, new PossibleValuesCellComparer());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own `IEqualityComparer<Cell>` for your `Cell` class that states equality when the `PossibleValues` are equal like this:

```
public class CellComparer : IEqualityComparer<Cell>
{
    public bool Equals(Cell x, Cell y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return ReferenceEquals(y, null);
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        return x.PossibleValues.SequenceEqual(y.PossibleValues);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Cell obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 1;
            foreach (int h in obj.PossibleValues.Select(v => v?.GetHashCode() ?? 0))
                hash = (hash * 397) ^ h;
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this for a simple LINQ grouping like this:

```
var cellsGroupedByEqualValues = group.GroupBy(c => c, new CellComparer());
```

This returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Cell,Cell>>` and you can iterate through it and receive the number of matching cells:

```
foreach(var groupedCells in cellsGroupedByEqualValues)
    Console.WriteLine(groupedCells.Count());
```

But these contain duplicates since `GroupBy` generates a `IGrouping` for every `Cell` and adds all matching cells to that. *(still trying to find a good way around that)*

But for now you can tell for *every* `Cell` how many other `Cell`s with the same list of values there are.