# Immutable Collection Hashcode

Tags: c#, hash, collections

My object will has an Array of bytes, it may have thousands of elements. This array will be set during construction and then never change. I need to be able to compare the arrays from 2 separate objects to see if the are exactly the same.

I know I can use Enumerable.SequenceEqual to compare two values, but that has an overhead that I want to avoid.

My plan is to use something like this [Good GetHashCode() override for List of Foo objects respecting the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094867/good-gethashcode-override-for-list-of-foo-objects-respecting-the-order) right after generating the collection and storing that hash for comparison.

I am wondering if there is an immutable collection type build into C# or .Net that already does this, or if there is a better option I have overlooked.

Comment: Something like this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time/

Comment: HashCode is not good idea due to possible collision.  In real life, hash code is used to indicates that obejcts are "possible equal" or "definitely not equal".

Comment: @nopeflow "definitely not equal" is enough to avoid more costly *SequenceEqual* checks for every item...  SequenceEqual can be used only when hashcodes are equal....

Comment: @L.B Yeep, that's right and good place to improve performance - but we can't depend only on hash code ;)

Comment: @Darren - From what I can see those collections don't return any hashcodes for the collections... and I don't see anything that would save me time over just using an array or IEnumerable.

Comment: @nopeflow & L.B Yeep -- thanks for those tips - I will keep them in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put together a few different methods of comparing arrays of bytes, I have used an arbitrary array length of 10000 and assumed that both compared arrays are of the same length (because a "broad phase" length check is obviously not very interesting :) )

Perhaps you could use this as a basis for making a decision on which method to use when comparing the arrays for equality.

The results are the average of 5 iterations for three scenarios (equal, first element different and last element different) and the timings are in ms.

```
---------------
Identical elements
---------------
SequenceEqual: 5.98142
BasicEqual: 0.11864
UnsafeMemCmp: 0.15542
SafeMemCmp: 0.12896
---------------
First element different
---------------
SequenceEqual: 0.00056
BasicEqual: 0.00012
UnsafeMemCmp: 0.0002
SafeMemCmp: 0.00182
---------------
Last element different
---------------
SequenceEqual: 0.14942
BasicEqual: 0.03178
UnsafeMemCmp: 0.0015
SafeMemCmp: 0.00326
---------------
```

The 4 methods I have chosen are:

*SequentalEqual*

```
static bool SequenceEqual(byte[] arr1, byte[] arr2)
{
    return arr1.SequenceEqual(arr2);
}
```

*BasicEqual*

```
static bool BasicEqual(byte[] arr1, byte[] arr2)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])
            return false;
     return true;
}
```

*UnsafeMemCmp*

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern unsafe int memcmp(byte* b1, byte* b2, int count);

static unsafe bool UnsafeMemCmp(byte[] arr1, byte[] arr2)
{
    fixed (byte* b1 = arr1, b2 = arr2)
    {
        return memcmp(b1, b2, 10000) == 0;
    }
}
```

*SafeMemCmp*

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int memcmp(IntPtr b1, IntPtr b2, int count);

static bool SafeMemCmp(byte[] arr1, byte[] arr2)
{
    var a = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(arr1.Length);
    var b = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(arr2.Length);

    try
    {        
        Marshal.Copy(arr1, 0, a, arr1.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(arr2, 0, b, arr2.Length);

        return memcmp(a, b, 10000) == 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(a);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(b);
    }
}
```

For completion, the tests were run using the following method:

```
static void RunTest(string name, Func<byte[], byte[], bool> action, byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.Zero;

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        _stopwatch.Reset();
        _stopwatch.Start();
        action(a, b);
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        total += _stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + (total.TotalMilliseconds / 5));
}
```

Comment: thanks... You have `SafeEquals` in your list - I assume that maps to the method for `BasicEqual` in the code section.

Comment: Yes indeed, I modified it after writing the answer... I'll edit :)