# I'd like to know how can I write good GetHashCode() for ordered list

Tags: c#, gethashcode

I made a class that include `List<T>`.(`T` is a struct I made.) And I want to override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`. So I need to make HashCode from `List<T>`. How can I make good HashCode from ordered list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good GetHashCode() override for List of Foo objects respecting the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094867/good-gethashcode-override-for-list-of-foo-objects-respecting-the-order)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Jon Skeet provides a great example on a similar post:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 19;
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + foo.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Primes are generally very useful when hashing. If you're interested to know why, you'll have to look up the maths because people are most likely better at explaining that than I am.