# Hashset of Lists

Tags: c#, list, hashset

I am using a `HashSet` of `List` elements in C#. However, it doesn't get rid of duplicate `List` elements.

```
HashSet<List<int>> set = new HashSet<List<int>>();
List<int> l1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
List<int> l2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
set.Add(l1);
set.Add(l2);
foreach (List<int> l in set) {
    foreach(int i in l) {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
1 2
1 2
```

However, I want the output to be just:

```
1 2
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Um, maybe you want a hashset of int, not a hashset of list of int?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar No, I do want a hashset of lists.

Comment: In that case you do need to implement a custom comparer, as per David's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<List<int>>` implementation that checks the contents of the lists.

```
public class ListEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        if (x is null && y is null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (x is null || y is null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (x.Count != y.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    // taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8094931/1165998
    public int GetHashCode(List<int> obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 19;
            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + item.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

When used with your example, it produces only one set of `1 2` results:

```
HashSet<List<int>> set = new HashSet<List<int>>(new ListEqualityComparer());
List<int> l1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
List<int> l2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
set.Add(l1);
set.Add(l2);
foreach (List<int> l in set)
{
    foreach (int i in l)
    {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```