# How to check if a key press or not while i'm not in the form?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a form that is running but not in the focus.
Now I want to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>NUM1</kbd> so the form which is not in the foreground catches it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible with a keyboard hook, which your application installs when it starts up and remove it on an app close.

This should get you started, you need to know/understand fundamentals of Win32 API for this!
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C