# C# screenshot application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

What should I use in C# windows forms to create a app to make screenshot like Yahoo Messenger does?

This is an example:
[image]

How is that transparent cover made? A form?

Comment: What do mean when you say `a screenshot app` I would suggest re-tuning this question before others start down marking / voting to close this non question

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a global keyboard hook and check for the input of the printscreen key (prt sc)

Take a look at this:
[Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)

Second thing is to take a screenshot of the whole screen.

```
    Size res = new Size(
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
);
Point ptr = new Point(
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y
);

using (var bmp = new Bitmap(res.Width, res.Height))
{
    using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(gmp))
    {
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(ptr.X, ptr.Y, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }
}
```

Now all you have to is implement some way to crop the screenshot. This is not a spoonfeeding community, so the rest is up to you, besides you have to be more specific.