# How to get key down event in c# using background worker(service)?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am developing c# application. where i want to notice all the physical key down by the user. For example if user is writing some document then my application should also notice the user string (message/document which he is writing).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Global Hooks. Take a look at

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C