# Get Data in Application from Barcode Scanner (usb)

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode-scanner

I have a plug and play Barcode scanner. The Barcode scanner return data at the cursor position(as HID Device). The data can be captured from any application with the focus. I don't have a text box in my application so i couldn't set the focus on my application and the data must be captured only in my application(Windows form). I'm not sure where should i start. Any help would be helpful.

Code As if now

```
DateTime lastKeystroke = new DateTime(0);
List<char> barcode = new List<char>(10);
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // check timing (keystrokes within 100 ms)
        TimeSpan elapsed = (DateTime.Now - lastKeystroke);
        if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 100)
            barcode.Clear();

        // record keystroke & timestamp
        barcode.Add(e.KeyChar);
        lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now;

        // process barcode
        if (e.KeyChar == 13 && _barcode.Count > 0)
        {
            string msg = new String(barcode.ToArray());
            MessageBox.Show(msg); //I get Value here
            barcode.Clear();
        }
    }
```

This works fine. but the problem is when my form is in Focus i get data i can work with it. but when my form doesn't have focus, meaning if it is minimized or the Some other application is opened , i don't get the data

Comment: does the scanner has an API too?

Comment: @pm100 : No the Barcode scanner doesn't have any API.

Comment: Barcode scanners usually act like a keyboard and send keystrokes, so you can check when the focus is on a `TextBox` and you scan something, the text should be written in `TextBox`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei : Thank you for your reply. as u said i use keypress event and i get data when my form is in Focus. but i don't get when my application doesn't have focus. I have updated the question.

Comment: You're not going to get any keyboard input (including keypress) if your app does not have the focus and a place to put keyboard input. The foreground application (the one  that *does* have the focus) receives all input.

Comment: Since most of scanners just behave like a keyboard you could use any technique that allows you to capture keystrokes without having focus. Global hooks comes to mind but that is pretty nasty.

Comment: @Frank J : Regarding Global hooks can you give me some reference and idea to use in my case.

Comment: [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: @Ken White : Is there a way where i could get the device Id or some unique field by which i could know if the keypress is from keyboard or some other device.

Comment: @user3501749: Most scanners don't unless you can configure your scanner to send one. As far as Windows  is concerned, keyboard input is keyboard input.