# How can I make my Form visible/invisible by pressing insert?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to find out how to making my form invisible when I press insert and when I press insert again it makes the form visible. I try to find out how, but no one seems to have what I am looking for.

Comment: You are looking for a global keyboard hook.  Hookinginsert globally is a terrible idea.

Comment: Invisible is easy. visible again is hard, because your app will lose focus and give input to another program.

Comment: Is this in WinForms? WPF? UWP? ASP.NET? Silverlight?

Comment: this is in winforms

Comment: Please, review the answers and mark the correct if it suits your problem.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example how you can manipulate Form's visibility by handling the Insert key down:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Don't forget to enable Form.KeyPreview in order to receive key down events
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)
        {
            Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can set `Visible` back to `true` to make it visible. However, you will not be able to do this, because Form became invisible and doesn't receive key down events anymore. In this case you can try to set the global hotkey using, for example, the [GlobalHotKey](https://github.com/kirmir/GlobalHotKey) library described [here](https://kirmir.com/2012/07/15/setting-up-system-wide-hot-keys/). Note also, that it doesn't make sense to set a single key (e.g. Insert) as global hotkey as in most cases system or another application will capture it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
private void InfoForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert) Opacity = Opacity == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

For this to work you need to turn on the Form's `KeyPreview` property!

But turning visiblity back on  (or to be precise turning off opacity) will **only** work if no **other** program has received **`focus`** in the meantime.

If that might happen you need to set a [global keyboard hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application); make sure to pass the Insert key back on or else many other programms will no longer work right.. All in all I would not recommend it..

I'm not sure when the whole idea might make sense. One answer could be to show or hide a popup data window that is only meant to show some additional information popping up from a base data window.

In that case you could simply close the window whenever it gets deactivated:

```
private void InfoForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```