# How do I make my code run when it is not selected?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a c# console application and I want it to monitor all keyboard input, even when other programs have focus, so that if a person hits a specific key combination (from anywhere), my code will be activated.

Currently when I run my program and then select another program, my program does not do anything when I enter the key combination.

A thread might be a good idea.

Sorry for my grammar and English. I try to explain it good.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Comment: You want to build some kind of key logger?

Comment: Threading won't help, you need to hook into the operating system keyboard events. Search for keylogger.

Comment: This quest is like a black hole. Can you please explain  more in detail or share some code so that we can help you.

Comment: Can you be any more vague in your question?

Comment: I made an attempt to clarify your question. Please roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 2):

Console application is not suitable for that. you should be looking for Keyboard Hook.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application).

Comment: If your answer is a link to another, similar question, wouldn't it be more appropriate to mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: @RufusL I usually do that, but in this question the user hasn't asked how should he use hooks, and actually his question shows that he does not know about hooks. So I wanted to suggest him to search about hooks. I thought a question about hooks would be of more help. but it is not the same question to mark it as duplicate