# C# global keyboard hook, that opens a form from a console application

Tags: c#, forms, hotkeys, global-hotkey

So I have a C# Console Application with a Form, which I want to open using hotkeys. Let's say for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> opens the form. So I got the code to handle a globalkeylistener now, but it looks like I failed by implementing it. It made a while loop to prevent it from closing the program and I tryed to get an input from the user with the kbh_OnKeyPressed method.

I tryed to implement it this way:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Globalkey
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotkey(int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

        private static bool lctrlKeyPressed;
        private static bool f1KeyPressed;


        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            LowLevelKeyboardHook kbh = new LowLevelKeyboardHook();
            kbh.OnKeyPressed += kbh_OnKeyPressed;
            kbh.OnKeyUnpressed += kbh_OnKeyUnpressed;
            kbh.HookKeyboard();

            while(true) { }

        }

        private static void kbh_OnKeyUnpressed(object sender, Keys e)
        {
            if (e == Keys.LControlKey)
            {
                lctrlKeyPressed = false;
                Console.WriteLine("CTRL unpressed");
            }
            else if (e == Keys.F1)
            {
                f1KeyPressed = false;
                Console.WriteLine("F1 unpressed");
            }
        }

        private static void kbh_OnKeyPressed(object sender, Keys e)
        {
            if (e == Keys.LControlKey)
            {
                lctrlKeyPressed = true;
                Console.WriteLine("CTRL pressed");
            }
            else if (e == Keys.F1)
            {
                f1KeyPressed = true;
                Console.WriteLine("F1 pressed");
            }
            CheckKeyCombo();
        }

        static void CheckKeyCombo()
        {
            if (lctrlKeyPressed && f1KeyPressed)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just forgot to say that I want to open it while the program is running, so "ctrl + <" would have to trigger: Application.Run(new Form1());

Comment: Just catch this key combo in keydown event, and then call the form

Comment: Well it has to be global which means that I can access the hotkey while the program isn't focused

Comment: Then look no further, [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) comes to the rescue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you need is a Lowlevel Keyboard Hook.

This could look somewhat like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class LowLevelKeyboardHook
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public event EventHandler<Keys> OnKeyPressed;
    public event EventHandler<Keys> OnKeyUnpressed;

    private LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc;
    private IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public LowLevelKeyboardHook()
    {
        _proc = HookCallback;
    }

    public void HookKeyboard()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    }

    public void UnHookKeyboard()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            OnKeyPressed.Invoke(this, ((Keys)vkCode));
        }
        else if(nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP ||wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYUP)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            OnKeyUnpressed.Invoke(this, ((Keys)vkCode));
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);            
    }
}
```

To implement it, you could use something like this:

```
kbh = new LowLevelKeyboardHook();
kbh.OnKeyPressed += kbh_OnKeyPressed;
kbh.OnKeyUnpressed += kbh_OnKeyUnpressed;
kbh.HookKeyboard();
```

The event could be handled like that:

```
bool lctrlKeyPressed;
bool f1KeyPressed;

void kbh_OnKeyPressed(object sender, Keys e)
{
    if (e == Keys.LControlKey)
    {
        lctrlKeyPressed = true;
    }
    else if (e == Keys.F1)
    {
        f1KeyPressed= true;
    }
    CheckKeyCombo();
}

void kbh_OnKeyUnPressed(object sender, Keys e)
{
    if (e == Keys.LControlKey)
    {
        lctrlKeyPressed = false;
    }
    else if (e == Keys.F1)
    {
        f1KeyPressed= false;
    }
}

void CheckKeyCombo()
{
    if (lctrlKeyPressed && f1KeyPressed)
    {
        //Open Form
    }
}
```

For actual understanding, i would recommend you to have a read on P/Invoke. That is making use of the unmanaged APIs that windows provides.

For a full list of P/Invoke possibilites, [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net) is a great source.

For better understanding in general, [The official MSDN Website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx) is a good source, too.

**EDIT:**

It seems like you're actually using a Console Application, not a WinForm one. In that case, you have to run the program a bit differently:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    LowLevelKeyboardHook kbh = new LowLevelKeyboardHook();
    kbh.OnKeyPressed += kbh_OnKeyPressed;
    kbh.OnKeyUnpressed += kbh_OnKeyUnpressed;
    kbh.HookKeyboard();

    Application.Run();

    kbh.UnHookKeyboard();

}
```

The Run() method of the Application Class starts a standard loop for your application. This is necessary for the Hook to work, because a mere Console Application without this loop is, as far as I know, not capable of triggering those global key events.

Using this implementation, pressing and releasing the defined keys gives the following output:

[image: Console Output]

Note: I obviously replaced

`Application.Run(new Form1());`

in the `CheckKeyCombo()` method with

`Console.WriteLine("KeyCombo pressed");`

Comment: Hmm thanks, but how can I handle multiple key inputs with that code?

Comment: I've extended the event handling code sample to fit your needs. Note, I've used CTRL + F1, because I'm really not sure about the "<" sign in the Keys enum. For a full list, visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Haha it isn't a console application

Comment: hmm okay, i was pretty sure because the solution fits console applications :D apologies!

Comment: How to set hook to another process ?

Comment: @nim Can you give me a bit more context? Some sample code or anything? Something that can help me understand what you're trying to achieve. :)

Comment: thank you so much for answering this question. The linked apparent answer is far far below the standard of your answer.

Comment: Dotnet core doesn't know what the type `Keys` is / it doesn't know how to import