# How properly create a global mouse hotkey in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse, global-hotkey

I am trying to create global mouse hotkeys in my program using `SetWindowsHookEx()`. So far I have tried to create them like in one post I have seen here but, I dont really know how to finsh this.
The problem is currently that I dont exactly know what _globalMouseHookCallback is.

This is what I have written so far:

```
class GlobalHotkey
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    internal delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private IntPtr _hGlobalMouseHook;


    MainWindow _m;

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
    private const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
    private const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;

    private static IntPtr hook = IntPtr.Zero;

    public GlobalHotkey(MainWindow m)
    {
        _m = m;
    }

    public void SetUpHook()
    {
        _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Setting up global Hotkey \n");

        _globalMouseHookCallback = LowLevelMouseProc;

        _hGlobalMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, _globalMouseHookCallback, Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]), 0);

        if (_hGlobalMouseHook == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Unable to set up global mouse hook\n");
        }
    }

    public void ClearHook()
    {
        _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Deleting global mouse hook\n");

        if (_hGlobalMouseHook != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (!UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hGlobalMouseHook))
            {
                _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Unable to delete global mouse hook\n");
            }

            _hGlobalMouseHook = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

    }

    public int LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            var wmMouse = wParam;

            if (wmMouse == (IntPtr)WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Right Mouse down");
            }
            if (wmMouse == (IntPtr)WM_LBUTTONUP)
            {
                _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Left Mouse up");
            }

            if (wmMouse == (IntPtr)WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Right Mouse down");
            }
            if (wmMouse == (IntPtr)WM_RBUTTONUP)
            {
                _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Right Mouse up");
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hGlobalMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

This global hotkey stuff is pretty hard is there like a tutorial that explains it easily for newbs like me :P ?

**EDIT**
So I tried adapting Koby Ducks example to my code.

This is my Hotkey class:

```
class GlobalHotkey
{

    MainWindow _m;

    private static readonly object sSyncObj = new object();
    private static readonly HashSet<Key> sDownKeys = new HashSet<Key>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<Key, Action> sPressActions = new Dictionary<Key, Action>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<Key, Action> sReleaseActions = new Dictionary<Key, Action>();

    public GlobalHotkey(MainWindow m)
    {
        _m = m;

    }

    public static void ProcessKeyDown(KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        var key = args.Key;
        var action = default(Action);
        lock (sSyncObj)
        {
            if (!sDownKeys.Contains(key))
            {
                sDownKeys.Add(key);

                if (sPressActions.TryGetValue(key, out action))
                {
                    args.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        action.Invoke();
    }

    public static void ProcessKeyUp(KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        var key = args.Key;
        var action = default(Action);
        lock (sSyncObj)
        {
            if (sDownKeys.Remove(key))
            {
                if (sReleaseActions.TryGetValue(key, out action))
                {
                    args.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        action.Invoke();
    }

    public static void AttachPressAction(Key key, Action action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
        }

        lock (sSyncObj)
        {
            sPressActions.Add(key, action);
        }
    }

    public static bool DetachPressAction(Key key)
    {
        lock (sSyncObj)
        {
            return sPressActions.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    public static void AttachReleaseAction(Key key, Action action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
        }

        lock (sSyncObj)
        {
            sReleaseActions.Add(key, action);
        }
    }

    public static bool DetachReleaseAction(Key key)
    {
        lock (sSyncObj)
        {
            return sReleaseActions.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

And I created my action

```
public void MyTestAction()
    {
        rtbLog.AppendText("The B key was pressed");
    }
myAction = new Action(MyTestAction);
```

But as soon as I added my Eventhandlers to the PreviewKeyUp- and Down Event it gave me an error saying that the Parameters of ProcessKeyUp- and Down, are not the same as PreviewKeyUp- and Down.

```
PreviewKeyDown += GlobalHotkey.ProcessKeyDown;
PreviewKeyUp += GlobalHotkey.ProcessKeyUp;
```

Comment: Meaning you want to catch keyboard and mouse events that happen even when your app doesn't have focus?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Comment: See my updated answer. The problem was I apparently left out the sender parameter. The vast majority of Windows GUI event are of the form `(object sender, EventArgs args)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** For input regardless of the currently focused window(aka "global"), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604417/3446285) on the Win32 keyboard API.

For input while your app is focused(aka "local"), you could use preview events.

```
public static class HotKeySystem
{
    public static void ProcessKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        var key = args.Key;
        var action = default(Action);
        lock (sSyncObj) {
            if (!sDownKeys.Contains(key)) {
                sDownKeys.Add(key);
                if (sPressActions.TryGetValue(key, out action)) {
                    args.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // Invoke outside of the lock.
        action?.Invoke();
    }
    public static void ProcessKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        var key = args.Key;
        var action = default(Action);
        lock (sSyncObj) {
            if (sDownKeys.Remove(key)) {
                if (sReleaseActions.TryGetValue(key, out action)) {
                    args.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // Invoke outside of the lock.
        action?.Invoke();
    }
    public static void AttachPressAction(KeyCode key, Action action)
    {
        if (action == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
        }
        lock (sSyncObj) {
            sPressActions.Add(key, action);
        }
    }
    public static bool DetachPressAction(KeyCode key)
    {
        lock (sSyncObj) {
            return sPressActions.Remove(key);
        }
    }
    public static void AttachReleaseAction(KeyCode key, Action action)
    {
        if (action == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
        }
        lock (sSyncObj) {
            sReleaseActions.Add(key, action);
        }
    }
    public static bool DetachReleaseAction(KeyCode key)
    {
        lock (sSyncObj) {
            return sReleaseActions.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    private static readonly object sSyncObj = new object();
    // The keys that are currently down.
    private static readonly HashSet<KeyCode> sDownKeys = new HashSet<KeyCode>();
    // Actions triggered when a key was up, but is now down.
    private static readonly Dictionary<KeyCode, Action> sPressActions = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Action>();
    // Actions triggered when a key was down, but is now up.
    private static readonly Dictionary<KeyCode, Action> sReleaseActions = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Action>();
}

// When possible, subclass your windows from this to automatically add hotkey support.
public class HotKeyWindow : Window
{
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        HotKeySystem.ProcessKeyDown(this, args);
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(args);
    }
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyUp(KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        HotKeySystem.ProcessKeyUp(this, args);
        base.OnPreviewKeyUp(args);
    }
}

// When not possible, attach event handlers like this:
window.PreviewKeyDown += HotKeySystem.ProcessKeyDown;
window.PreviewKeyUp += HotKeySystem.ProcessKeyUp;

// Use it like this:
HotKeySystem.AttachPressAction(KeyCode.F1, () => {
    // F1 hotkey functionality.
});
```

Regardless of if you're using this method or the Win32 API, consider the implications. If you have 'A' bound, then you won't be able to input 'a' or 'A' into text input controls. One way to work around this is:

```
public static void ProcessKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
    // Detect keyboard input controls you may have issues with.
    // If one has keyboard focus, skip hotkey processing.
    if (Keyboard.FocusedElement is TextBox) {
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: OnPreviewMouseDown/Up achieves the same thing with mouse input. To detect global mouse input without using the Win32 API, use [CaptureMouse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it as the accepted answer. If not, comment and perhaps I can further help.

Comment: I have this now but I hav a problem which I wrote down in my question.

Comment: Updated with the fix. It was a simple signature mismatch that you only experience when using the 2nd option(attaching event handlers).

Comment: It now works but only if the application is focused, but what I need is that even when the application is not focused, the code has to be executed.

Comment: I addressed both global and local keyboard input. Please read the post I linked to in the first part of my answer. In a nutshell, you need to use the Win32 API for global input, and app level handlers for local input(my example or similar).