# Monitoring a keyboard in a non-active window

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook

How would one listen to key presses on a specific keyboard in a background c# process?

Context: We have a barcode scanner which currently requires a window to be active to read what's scanned.  At the moment the window has to be active which isn't ideal.

Comment: Using a [global keyboard hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)?