# How to detect which keyboard was pressed in a GlobalKeyboardHook?

Tags: c#, wpf

Using a Global Keyboard Hook (as here: 
[Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)), how would one detect which keyboard has been pressed from the event fired?

Comment: Just so we're clear, you really mean "keyboard"? As in, you have multiple keyboards, you need to know if the user pressed the A button on the left or the right keyboard (as an example)?

Comment: Exactly that yes

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that with global hooks. If you need to know which device was used, use DirectInput. It is much more low-level and MS considers it outdated, but it does its job and also it has an additional advantage of being much more robust then global hooks as it does not involve any dll injections or other dark practices.

Comment: Thanks - I've started on a direction like that

Answer (score -1):

here is an example:

```
keyBoardHook = new KeyboardHook(true);
keyBoardHook.KeyDown += KeyBoardHook_KeyDown;
keyBoardHook.KeyUp += KeyBoardHook_KeyUp;

private void KeyBoardHook_KeyUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key, bool Shift, bool Ctrl, bool Alt)
    {
        if (key == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F1)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    private void KeyBoardHook_KeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key, bool Shift, bool Ctrl, bool Alt)
    {
        if (key == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F1)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Additionally, every answer should contain some explanation, not just an unexplained snippet of code.

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood the question. i thought he was asking how to detect which key pressed