# How do I unhook a global hook from another process?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Here's my current setup: I have a C++ DLL that hooks one of its functions globally to every process running on the computer. The hooking is done in `DLLMain` using the `SetWindowsHookEx` winapi function, and I'm hooking to the `WH_CBT` and `WH_SHELL` events. I also have a C# application that loads the DLL with p/invoke (`LoadLibrary()`) which triggers the installation of the hooks from `DLLMain`. The handlers in the DLL are sending event information to the C# app through a named pipe.

Based on what I've read on the [microsoft documentary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa), these events will be handled on the target process's thread, and have to be installed by a standalone C++ DLL (unlike WH_MOUSE_LL and WH_KEYBOARD_LL that can be installed by any application, even [straight from a C# app using p/invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604417/3314466)).

So far everything works fine; the managed app is receiving data as it should. The problem arises when I shut down the application, because the handlers are still hooked, and therefore the DLL file is in use and can't be deleted.

Since the handler is not running in my application, but instead it's injected into other processes running on my computer, the C# app can't just simply call `UnhookWindowsHookEx` or `FreeLibrary`, because the pointer of the event handler belongs to other processes.

**The question:**

How can I trigger an unhook routine from the managed application that makes sure that the DLL is not in use anymore by any process?

**Here's what i've tried:**

The only solution that I wan able to come up with is to create an exit event (with `CreateEvent`) and every time the handler receives `WH_CBT` or `WH_SHELL` message, it checks if the exit event is set, in which case it unhooks itself from the process it belongs to and returns before processing the message.

The problem with this approach is that after I shut down my application and unload the DLL, I have to wait until the remaining processes receive an WH event at least once, so the handler belonging to them can unhook itself.

Here's the code of the DLL:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>

HANDLE hTERM;
HHOOK hCBT;
HHOOK hShell;

void __declspec(dllexport) InstallHooks(HMODULE h);
void __declspec(dllexport) RemoveHooks();

int Continue()
{
    return WAIT_TIMEOUT == WaitForSingleObject(hTERM, 0);
}

LRESULT FAR PASCAL _cbtProc(int c, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
    if (!Continue()) { RemoveHooks(); return 0; }   
    // Handling the message ...
    return CallNextHookEx(0, c, w, l);
}

LRESULT FAR PASCAL _shellProc(int c, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
    if (!Continue()) { RemoveHooks(); return 0; }
    // Handling the message ...
    return CallNextHookEx(0, c, w, l);
}

void InstallHooks(HMODULE h)
{
    hTERM = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, 0, __TEXT("{0C3ED513-F38C-4996-8130-F9A3C93D890B}"));
    if (!Continue())
        return;
    hCBT = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, _cbtProc, h, 0);
    hShell = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, _shellProc, h, 0);
}

void RemoveHooks()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hCBT);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hShell);
    if (hTERM) CloseHandle(hTERM); hTERM = 0;
}

int FAR PASCAL DllMain(HMODULE h, DWORD r, void* p)
{
    switch (r)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: InstallHooks(h); break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: RemoveHooks(); break;
        default: break;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

There is nothing special about the source code of the managed C# app, because the only thing it does is that it calls `LoadLibrary` on start, handles the messages coming from the pipe, and finally sets the exit event with an other p/invoke call when needed.

Comment: "*The hooking is done in DLLMain*" - that is the completely wrong place to handle that. Every time the DLL is injected into a new process, it is going to install a new hook. The **correct** solution is to have your DLL export its `InstallHooks()` and `RemoveHooks()` functions, and then have ONLY your C# app call them AFTER it has loaded the DLL into itself. That single set of hooks will then inject the DLL into all running processes as needed WITHOUT having to call `SetWindowsHookEx` each time. And you should NOT be calling `UnhookWindowsHookEx()` from *inside* the hook callbacks themselves.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Which approach would you recommend for loading the DLL in C#? Should I p/invoke `LoadLibrary`, get the method's pointer with `GetProcAddress` and call it that way, or should I go with the `DllImport` attribute?

Comment: Use `DllImport`, it is a wrapper for `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`, so there is no need to call them directly.

Comment: how/why your dll loaded to another process ? you inject it somehow manually ? or it loaded to process because you call `SetWindowsHookEx` in your process ? in this case you of course not need call `SetWindowsHookEx` second time on load in target process - because it and loaded because hook already instaled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*The hooking is done in DLLMain*" - that is the completely wrong place to handle this.

Every time the DLL is loaded into a new process, it is going to install a new set of Shell/CBT hooks, which you DO NOT want/need to happen.  You only need 1 set.

The **correct** solution is to have your DLL export its `InstallHooks()` and `RemoveHooks()` functions, and then have ONLY your C# app call them AFTER it has loaded the DLL into itself.  That single set of hooks will handle loading the DLL into all running processes as needed WITHOUT you having to call `SetWindowsHookEx()` each time.

Also, DO NOT call `UnhookWindowsHookEx()` from *inside* the hook callbacks themselves.  Before the C# app exits, it should call `RemoveHooks()`, which can then signal the `hTerm` event before calling `UnhookWindowsHookEx()`.  The callbacks should simply exit if `Continue()` returns false, nothing more.  But DO NOT skip calling `CallNextHookEx()` even if `Continue()` returns false, as there may be additional hooks installed by other apps, and you DO NOT want to break them.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <windows.h>

HMODULE hModule = NULL;
HANDLE hTERM = NULL;
HHOOK hCBT = NULL;
HHOOK hShell = NULL;

static bool Continue()
{
    return (WAIT_TIMEOUT == WaitForSingleObject(hTERM, 0));
}

LRESULT CALLBACK _cbtProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (Continue()) {
        // Handle the message ...
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK _shellProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (Continue()) {
        // Handle the message ...
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}

__declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPI InstallHooks()
{
    if (!Continue())
        return FALSE;

    if (!hCBT)
        hCBT = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, _cbtProc, hModule, 0);

    if (!hShell)
        hShell = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, _shellProc, hModule, 0);

    return ((hCBT) && (hShell)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void WINAPI RemoveHooks()
{
    if (hTERM)
        SetEvent(hTERM);

    if (hCBT) {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hCBT);
        hCBT = NULL;
    }

    if (hShell) {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hShell);
        hShell = NULL;
    }
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, void* lpvReserved)
{
    hModule = hinstDLL;

    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hTERM = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, TEXT("{0C3ED513-F38C-4996-8130-F9A3C93D890B}"));
            if (!hTERM) return FALSE;
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            if (hTERM) {
                CloseHandle(hTERM);
                hTERM = NULL;
            }
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Then, your C# app can simply load the DLL and call `InstallHooks()` and `RemoveHooks()` when needed.  For instance, using PInvoke calls at app startup and shutdown, respectively.