# Is it possible to call a specific method every time a button is pressed, even when the console is not expecting user input?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I'm making a program for differentiating functions and want to call a specific method as soon as "esc" is pressed.

So far I've tried finding an answer through Google, but I can't seem to find anything that works. Does anyone know if this is possible in a C# console application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 0):

There is no event to listen for key presses. Only `Console.ReadKey`. But you can turn it into a callback using `Task`s. Like so:

```cs
public static void RegisterKeyHandler(Action<ConsoleKeyInfo> handler)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
            handler(key);
        }
    });
}
```

This only receives keys while the console window is focused.