# Detect Keyboard Input with ES3?

Tags: javascript, powershell, activex

Alright, I have perhaps a bit of a toughie for my...second ever StackOverflow question. Below is a hefty bit of background on my issue. Here is the TLDR: can I, using native Javascript, ActiveX objects, and through that PowerShell, capture keyboard input without popping up a window or using HTML?

BACKGROUND - I'm working in a specific game engine. Said game engine uses ES3, with apparently a few features of ES5 tacked on such as `array.indexOf()`, for plugin development. It's really not pretty, but recently some folks and I discovered we can still create ActiveXObjects, run powershell through that, and so forth. Through this, we're managing all kinds of things - the next step is, hopefully, to capture keyboard input.

Natively, the engine - SRPG Studio - can only detect a limited number of inputs, assigned starting at -1 for nothing, -2 for mouse, and 0 through 11 for Left, Up, Right, Down, and various other keys that are assignable in a config file once you export a game or demo. You cannot, natively, detect other keys - they use a hidden "root" command, `root.isInputState()`, which returns true or false if the value is from 0 to 11, and always returns true if it's higher, or always false if it's lower. I cannot see the code of the function itself, but I have tested various numbers, to the point of crashing the Test Play feature by inputting a number that is too large for it to parse - 30501850151. At random keypresses.

That was all background, and I apologize for how much there is. The question is as follows:

Can I detect and capture keyboard input using ActiveX or Powershell, using a method that will not require jQuery, NodeJs, or in fact *any* such additional modifications, as well as not using HTML, as the engine reads it as bad syntax? It would aid us in creating a communications interface for a recently developed PvP plugin.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Something like [global keyboard hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604417/3439404)? You can compile *in-line C#* in powershell easy…

Comment: @JosefZ This works gloriously so far. I suppose I will have to learn some C# to complete this project, but that is no problem.