# C# - Force using XP style alt-tab switcher

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard, windows-xp, alt-tab

I would like to ask if anyone would know a way how to force the old XP version of Alt-Tab dialog when inside my C# app.

[image: Old XP Style Windows APP Switcher]

There is definitely a way how to capture keyboard keys, for example here [Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application).
There could be a way to capture alt-tab with KeyPress or KeyDown and then send alt-alt-tab which would show the old version, but that is not a preferable way.

So how to force windows from C# to show the old alt-tab dialogue from the app? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  It's a lot of work to swim upstream.  I wouldn't bother unless you have a really good reason to do so.  Any "solution" here is going to be a nauseating hack.