# c# specific sequence keypress event any where in form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keypress

I am a beginner at C# and would like some advice on how to solve the following problem:

I want to make an event to enable some text boxes when **random** press the following key "ctrl + v + a" **anywhere in form**.

```
  private void test_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((int)e.KeyData == (int)Keys.Control + (int)Keys.V + (int)Keys.A)
        {
            textbox1.Enabled = true;
            textbox2.Enabled = true;

        }
    }
```

The following code is not working.

Comment: is it `WPF`/`WinForms`/`UWP` project?

Comment: @ekvalizer It is WinForms project.

Comment: What do you mean by random press? If I only press v. Would be enough for Enabling?

Comment: Whatever I do in a form and when I press a specific sequence of keys I want automatically enabling some textboxes. I will use that for calibrating some system and it need to be protected with specific sequence of keys.

Comment: @Berkay Like, you cannot put anything in a text box (it is disabled), until you unlock textbox by pressing specific sequence of keys (Ctlr+v+a or any other set sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to do this **Any Where In Form.**
The best way for doing this is override the `ProcessCmdKey` method of the Form.
But it has some Limitations. You can use `Control | Alt | Shift` keys only with one more key.

like:
`ctrl + V` works 
`ctrl + A` works 
`ctrl + alt + V` works 
`ctrl + alt + shift + V` works 
`ctrl + V + A` does not work
`ctrl + alt + V + A` does not work

so you have to use another keys for example use `ctrl + shift + V`

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.V):
                textbox1.Enabled = true;
                textbox2.Enabled = true;
                return true;

      // more keys if you want

            case (Keys.Control | Keys.H):
                MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
                return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want to track `key events` of forms.

**First**, you can `inherit` all your forms from base form (Form's `KeyPreview` property should be `True`), like;

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
    private static List<Keys> keyPress = new List<Keys>(); // to store the key values
    public BaseForm()
    {
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.BaseForm_KeyDown); // register event for all forms which inherits from BaseForm
    }

    private void BaseForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.C || e.KeyCode == Keys.V) // right now Control, C, V keys are included
        {

            if (keyPress.Any(x => x == e.KeyCode)) // If keypress list has the current key press so pattern is broken
            {
                keyPress.Clear(); //clear the list user should start again
            }
            else
            {
                keyPress.Add(e.KeyCode);
            }

            if (keyPress.Count > 2) 
            {
                this.Controls["textBox1"].Enabled = true; 
                keyPress.Clear(); // clear the keyPress list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So by doing this, you don't need to register keydown event for all your forms.

**Second**, you can use global key hook. (More information click [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)) At the main thread enterance `Low-LevelKeyboardHook` will be attached to the process and every key event will be catched at `HookCallback`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;

namespace KeyHookTryApp
{
   static class Program
   {
       private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
       private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
       private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
       private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
       private static Form1 f;
       private static List<Keys> keyPress = new List<Keys>();
       /// <summary>
       /// The main entry point for the application.
       /// </summary>
       [STAThread]
       static void Main()
       {
           _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           f = new Form1();
           Application.Run(f);
           UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
       }
       private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
       {
           using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
           using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
           {
               return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                   GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
           }
       }

       private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

       private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       {
           int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
           Keys key = (Keys)vkCode;

           if (nCode >= 0 && ((key == Keys.LControlKey || key == Keys.RControlKey) || key == Keys.C || key == Keys.V))
           {
               if (keyPress.Any(x => x == key))
               {
                   keyPress.Clear();
               }
               else
               {
                   keyPress.Add(key);
               } 

               if (keyPress.Count > 2)
               {
                   f.Controls["textBox1"].Enabled = true;
                   keyPress.Clear();
               }
           }
           else if(keyPress.Count > 0)
           {
               keyPress.Clear();
           }

           return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
       }

       [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
       private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

       [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
       [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
       private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

       [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
       private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

       [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
       private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
   }
}
```

If there are multiple forms. The form controls should be reachable from global, or the forms should have custom methods like `EnableTextBoxes()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `KeyEventArgs e` stores only one key I assume you have to store key `V` state.

```
private bool _keyVPressed;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _keyVPressed = _keyVPressed || KeyVPressed(e.KeyCode);
    if (e.Control && _keyVPressed && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) => _keyVPressed = !KeyVPressed(e.KeyCode);

private bool KeyVPressed(Keys k) => k is Keys.V;
```

And to apply this behaviour **anywhere in form** you need to attach the events to every control at your form

```
this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyUp);
//...
//some designer code
//...
this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
this.textBox1.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyUp);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to handle the `KeyDown` event and if the first key, say `A` is down and the `Ctrl` key, set a `bool` to `true` at the `Form` level to indicate that the sequence is starting. The next `KeyDown` event should be the second key in the sequence, say `V`, and the `Ctrl` key is down (still). If the `bool` you set at the start is still true, meaning the `Ctrl` key has not been released, then execute whatever you wanted to do. Use the `KeyUp` event to detect if the `Ctrl` key has been released and if it has, set the `bool` value to `false` because it's not in sequence.

The pseudocode would look like this:

- `private bool isSequence;`
- `KeyDown` event handler

  - `if (Ctrl && e.KeyData == Keys.A) { isSequence = true; }`
  - `if (Ctrl && e.KeyData == Keys.V && isSequence) { DoWhateverThing(); }`
- `KeyUp` event handler

  - `if (e.KeyData == Ctrl) { isSequence = false; }`

Answer (score 0):

you may miss '&&'
 `if ((int)e.KeyData == (int)Keys.Control && (int)e.KeyData == (int)Keys.V && (int)e.KeyData == (int)Keys.A))`

you can try this Javascript Code also:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  log.textContent += ` ${e.code}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give e.Control==true && e.KeyCode==Keys.V && e.Keycode==Keys.A in if condition