# Keybinds work after application hidden C#

Tags: c#

How can I code a keybind, that after hidden still works? Like the Win + G Shortcut, I have already researched of how I can do this, but there really is no results. I am almost confident that there is a solution. Thank you -FlyBlueTNT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Search for "global hotkey c#" and there are a lot of answers to your question