# Console app: How to continue receiving keystrokes when console window is not in focus

Tags: c#, console, console-application

i wrote a console app in c# that listens for specific keypresses on the keyboard and executes code afterwards. Everything works fine as long as the program is the active program.

But I want the program to run also when I "tabbed" out of it.

In other words: When I'm playing a computer game and I press F1, I want the code of my program to be executed.

Is there an easy way to implement it? Is it even possible with console applications?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The only way I know of is through global keyboard hooks as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application).  Not sure how easy it is to get working in a console application.

Comment: You need a global keyboard hook, and for that to work you need to run a [message pump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-application-run)