# Shortcut from keyboard C#

Tags: c#

I'm making a shortcut program in C#.
And I've done this piece of code that works, it just print ss when I press shift.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        while (true)
        {
            if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0)
                Console.WriteLine("ss");
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that while true is consuming 20% of my cpu so I want to optimize it (I will not increase sleep time) and it need to work from any windows focus (If I'm using another app and i press shift it have to print ss). I just want keep it reactive and decrease cpu usage. Do you know guys any tricks?

Comment: What you want is called a 'hook', in this case a keyboardhook. Search for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Yes but what code is deprecated i think form when net6 was relased

Comment: How do we know what version of C# / .Net you are using?