# Keyboard shortcut to not active application

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts

I have created an on-Screen Keyboard using WS_EX_NOACTIVATE

The problem is that i cannot use shortcuts in the on-screen keyboard. How can I make it possible to reacts on shortcuts from my keyboard application?

Comment: Do you mean that you can't inform other applications about shortcuts, pressed in your on-screen keyboard application? .... And what have you tried?

Comment: I mean that that I am able to make my keyboard application to do various action based on keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I don't know what you have tried but*

I recommend you to

register your own hotkeys

MSDN: [RegisterHotKey Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Set global hotkeys using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp)

or to monitor the pressed keys by yourself

MSDN: [GetAsyncKeyState Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

*Sorry for Community Wiki*