# Trouble with minimizing app to system tray

Tags: c#, wpf, system-tray

(WPF C#)
I want to minimize app to system tray, but without icon in taskbar:
[image]
So i set:

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Then undesirable icon disappeared but new bar appears on desktop!

[image]

Does somebody please have idea how to solve this problem after minimization?

Here is my important part of code:

```
private void stateChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (WindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
            {
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                var iconHandle = Properties.Resources.iconPaw.GetHicon();
                notifyIcon.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(iconHandle);
                notifyIcon.Click += new EventHandler(this.WindowsStateToNormal);
                notifyIcon.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Radek app";
                notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Welcome Message";
                notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info;
                notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
            }
        }

        private void WindowsStateToNormal(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon.Visible = false;               
        }
```

Comment: Please update the actual text of your message, don't put text in images.

Comment: i am gonna update it, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call

`this.Hide()`

when the form is minimized, preferably in the `Form.Resize` event handler:

```
private void frmMain_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
       this.Hide();
}
```

At some point you have to call

`this.Show()`

for example, in the `DoubleClick` handler of the `NotifyIcon`.

Comment: At WPF the name of event is StateChanged not Resize.

Answer (score 2):

Minimizing to the tray is a bit of a hack. To accomplish it you need to:

- Capture the minimize event and cancel it to prevent actual minimization
- Hide your application window with `this.Hide()`
- Listen for a click event on the taskbar icon and unhide the application window when clicked

Comment: I updated why this.Hide() does not work to me in question.

Comment: If you listen for a `Click` event from the `NotifyIcon` and do `this.Show()` it will show up immediately.

Comment: You can also configure the app now to show up in the taskbar.

Comment: That's normal windows behaviour; It hides icons that the user doesn't consider important. You can tell windows to always show your icon, but your application has no control over it.

Answer (score 1):

Your main window and its notification icon have no relation in the sense of activation.

You generally wouldn't want a running application to disappear and not be able to activate it again. Windows is therefore giving the user of your application the option to reactivate the window by either clicking its taskbar icon (which you want to hide) or by clicking its border (which you also don't want to show).

To circumvent this, simply hide your main window when it's minimized, and unhide it when your notification icon is (double)clicked.

This is explained with fewer words and more code in [minimize app to system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625421/minimize-app-to-system-tray), [How do I minimize a WinForms application to the notification area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317033/how-do-i-minimize-a-winforms-application-to-the-notification-area), [Minimize to tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140627/minimize-to-tray), [Minimizing a system windows form in tray in C# without seeing it hanging where taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641162/minimizing-a-system-windows-form-in-tray-in-c-sharp-without-seeing-it-hanging-wh) and so on.