# Global hotkey not working in some windows

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a WPF application with registered global hotkey, using Admin privileges.

I used NHotkey [(Source)](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NHotkey)

I tried `using NHotkey.Wpf`

```
HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace("HotkeyAction", Key.F9, ModifierKeys.Alt, HotkeyAction);
```

^ Works in most of windows and applications, but not in some games and I have no idea why. Can it be because they have administrator privileges too?

Then I tried `using NHotkey.WindowsForms;`

```
HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace("HotkeyAction", Keys.Alt | Keys.F9, HotkeyAction);
```

Same sitution, works everywhere except some games.

It is crucial for me to make it  work **everywhere** globally, system-wide. I ran out of options.

How can I implement a global hotkey in my WPF application?
I can switch development to console or winforms if it's required.

Comment: low-level keyboard hook ?

Comment: @OhMyGeo something like that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx ?

Comment: Yes this is a good one, with this you can intercept (hook) all the keyboard keys action (keydown, keyup etc) from the user.

Comment: I will give it my try and update question in case it fails. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/27309185/366064

Comment: @Bizz I would have to make a windows form application to make it work, wouldn't I? I tried with WPF and can't setup it.

Comment: Yes that's right. my mistake. however it can work for you. if you didn't find a better solution you can host the winForm inside your WPF window.

Comment: I had to remake whole project and make it in Windows Forms. It's okay, thank you.