# Hidden or show form C#

Tags: c#, show-hide

I have a problem with my project. Show I have a form and I want if I press F11 then my form will hide. If I press F12 my form will show again. How I can do that?

Here is my code:

```cs
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if(keyData == Keys.F11)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    if(keyData == Keys.F12)
    {
        this.Show();
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: What will be in focus when you pressing F11/F12 ?

Comment: You need to define a global `Hotkey` for your form. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp) to begin with.

Comment: Are you even able to have an application be in focus to receive key press events when it is minimized?

Comment: Is it the only Form you have? Why not minimize and restore, so the user won't panic..?