# Detect global keypress event using Mono + Gtk# on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, mono, gtk#

I'm trying to create a multiplatform desktop application.

I can register global hotkeys in Windows via P/Invoke like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27309185/164380).

I need to do the same in iOS (probably something with [MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute/))

What is the best practice to do this in iOS? 
Maybe there is some managed wrapper (in Gtk# or else?) so I can have the same codebase without ifdefs?

Thank you!

Comment: Say goodbye to such on iOS. An iOS app won't be allowed to do so.

Comment: I'm interested to know how you can get GTK# running on iOS. Have you done this? Cheers, M

Comment: @muszeo, just created Gtk# 2.0 project in Xamarin Studio

Comment: Ahh just seen your other comment -- makes sense now. mac OS.  In answering your question (well, sort of) the only way I've done this in GTK# is to hook int the keypress events on a window or widget, rather than globally. Sorry I can't be more help!

Answer (score 0):

GTK# is a wrapper to GTK lib written in C. It has a set of diffenet widget and all. It cannot even draw them without other components(GDK, atk and others). And when you're talking about iOS... If you want to create an app on iOS better use Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Forms or maybe you're talking about Mac OS?

Comment: Yes, I mean Mac OS desktop, sorry :)
And yes, I used Xamarin Studio to create Gtk# 2.0 Project which is later compiled on MacOS.