# Creating Global HotKeys VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a code that should start a timer when a key is pressed

code :

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyPress Lib "user32" Alias "GetAsyncKeyState" (ByVal key As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If GetKeyPress(Keys.LControlKey)  Then
        Timer1.Start()
    ElseIf GetKeyPress(Keys.LShiftKey) Then
        MsgBox("test")
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem here is whem i press left control timer1 starts and the message box appears also without clicking left shift. Help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any c# so i can not convert it to VB.Net :\, I would appreciate it if you covert it for me.

Comment: There is VB.Net version in the above link. just ignore the c#.