# Replace global hotkey

Tags: c#, .net, windows, hotkeys

I have a application that lives in the tray and I would like to define serveral hotkeys which will trigger events in my program.

I found inspiration from the excellent answer by @AaronLS in this question: [Set global hotkeys using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27309185/3064934)

If I register a hot key that are already defined by another application `RegisterHotKey` will return false and not register it. So how can I override or replace a hot key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I override or replace a hot key?

Ostensibly, you can't. That's by-design. Imagine if programs could hijack other program's hotkeys at-will - that wouldn't be pleasant.

[The Win32 `UnregisterHotKey` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unregisterhotkey) requires the caller to be the same thread that registered using `RegisterHotKey`, which makes it impossible for another program to unregister another program's hotkeys:

> `UnregisterHotKey` function:
>
> Frees a hot key previously **registered by the calling thread**.

What you *can* do is use Win32 to inject code into a remote process (assuming your own process has permsision to do this) then schedule code in that process's UI thread that then calls `UnregisterHotKey` - but that's another question.