# is there a way to press a key to make the form appear if it's not in focus?

Tags: c#

Example:
I'm browsing Amazon and I made a shopping list in C# forms, then I press a button to make that shopping list appear.

How would I do that because I can't find any out-of-form solution?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, try to submit additional info... Maybe some piece of code that help us understand what your issue is and what you have tried in order to solve it. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try using global hotkeys.
This works even if you're not focused on your program.
link: [Set global hotkeys using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp)