# Powershell Script is slow in opening an application

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a PowerShell script that opens a file when you press a hotkey like: `ctrl` + `alt` + `f` so that the app automatically runs every time the user presses those key combinations.

Now, the problem is that it indeed opens the application/file, but it takes 4-5 second to process it. I want the process to be fast enough so that the script opens the desired files the moment the user presses the key combinations and not seconds after it. I don't know what caused this slowdown...

Here's the script:

```
# Get the Desktop dir. path.
$desktopDir = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') 

# Create the shortcut object, initially in-memory only.
$shc = 
  (New-Object -ComObject 'Wscript.Shell').CreateShortcut("$desktopDir\linkthis.lnk") 

# Set the target executable (name will do if in $env:PATH).
$shc.TargetPath = 'C:\Users\abhay\Downloads\Test\script.py' 

# Assign the hotkey.
$shc.Hotkey = 'Ctrl+Alt+F'

$shc.Save()
```

(Code originally taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506825/how-to-create-a-hotkey-to-open-a-file-in-windows) asked by me earlier)

**Edit1:**

It isn't just the case with my `.py` script. It's the same when opening even notepad too! And the script indeed runs fast when I boot up my PC but after some time (2-3min) it causes the delay in opening again. I Just can't figure it out why...

**I don't know why it runs fast at the first 1-2 min and then slows down**

(Also, running the files manually is quick. It's just slow with the script)

**Edit 2**

Hey guys, I just discovered that it's just the case with my computer. It's working fine on my dad's PC with pentium processor  but I still appreciate any fix for my system if possible. Thanks. May god bless you and my father. Things are really wrong with me these days...

Comment: Your script doesn't open the file, it creates a shortcut that does.  Presumably the delay is in loading the Python environment to run the .py script.  Doesn't seem like a PowerShell issue.  What happens if you create the shortcut through the UI instead?

Comment: At least I would check as the very first thing that how much time each of the steps take

Comment: @boxdog check my edit!