# How to set global hotkey with maui and .net6 on windows?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui

I am learning maui and .net6 on windows.
I need to set global hotkey for a window,how to do it?

Comment: see this: [Set global hotkeys using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp) ?

Comment: @Luuk It is so old, I don't use winform.

Comment: Sorry, I could not smell that.... (and that info is not in your question)

Comment: If you find anything on this let me know. I need to popup my program from a shortcut

Comment: Some news about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm using [Sharphook](https://sharphook.tolik.io/v4.1.0/) instead
"VisualElement access keys" it is cross platform (windows, mac , linux)

I created a HookService to use from any page on my MAUI app.