# How to run a WinForms application with a keyboard shortcut combination?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I try to run my WinForms app (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) with C#? like Bablyon dictionary:) I can not find any knowledgeable trick. Can you show me how to run app. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> combination?

I am using Visual Studio 2008, if it matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what Babylon dictionary is, but chances are this is not implemented in C#. Windows has built-in functionality for launching applications with keyboard shortcuts. You can assign any combination you want to a particular shortcut, and whenever you press those keys, Windows will launch that program.

For example, you could assign the Calculator application to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>. To do this:

1. Find or create a shortcut to the application you wish to launch. (Your Start menu or desktop is a good place to look.)
2. Right-click on the shortcut, and select "Properties" from the drop-down menu.
      [image]
3. In the Properties window, open the "Shortcut" tab and click in the "Shortcut Key" box.
4. Press the key combination that you wish to use to start the application.
          [image]
5. Finally, click OK. Now, pressing that key combination from anywhere should launch your application.

Answer (score 2):

i usually create a shortcut and do  [this](http://smallvoid.com/article/windows-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to global hotkeys? Try this:

[Best way to tackle global hotkey processing in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81150/best-way-to-tackle-global-hotkey-processing-in-c/2611761#2611761)

Comment: This will only work if your application is already open. What you're doing is setting a low-level keyboard hook that your application can recognize, no matter what other application currently has the foreground focus. If you're trying to start your application for the first time, it won't be alive to listen for the hotkeys.

Comment: I know, but since the OP mentioned he wants behavior similar to Babylon dictionary, I believe this is the behavior he's referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a windows thing, isn't it?
Open the properties dialog for the shortcut to you App. There you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in the Shortcut key textbox.