# C# - on key press open window

Tags: c#, keyboard

I'm making a simple application. I have a button, that hides the application, and an icon is displayed in the Tray menu. What I want is, when the user presses a combination of buttons (let's say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>), the application will open up again.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81150/best-way-to-tackle-global-hotkey-processing-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [keyboard-hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) to catch the key combination

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the appropriate library at http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/