# Programming a hotkey utility

Tags: programming-languages, keyboard, hotkeys, keyhook

I've got a project, where I need to use hotkeys, that would work globally through the whole Windows OS. Now, from my knowledge I only know how to read Key events on current form. How would I go about programming a hotkey utility? And what would be the best language for it?

Thanks

Comment: Which platform? windows/linux/mac?

Comment: need OS support! check its core API(system calls).

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81150/best-way-to-tackle-global-hotkey-processing-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C#/.Net and a low-level hook (using Interops), have a look at Stephen Toubs example here (complete with source):

[**Low-Level Keyboard Hook in C#**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx)

For a more complete example (also C#/.Net and Interops), but with everthing neatly contained in a separate class, including trapping key presses using normal Events on the client side, check this out (the link to the actual source is in the blog text, a bit tricky to spot):

[**Global hotkeys with .NET**](http://bloggablea.wordpress.com/2007/05/01/global-hotkeys-with-net/)

Comment: Simply linking to web pages without providing an excerpt is not considered a proper answer.

Comment: Ok, added more information about the link targets.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this. even vhen the program is not active it should respond for a key press.
in windows,

```
#include<windows.h>
if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x41)){
     //do somethong here
 }
```

note: refer virtual key stats http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx