# Proper way of creating a background hotkey with WPF C#? (preferably without using legacy code)

Tags: c#, wpf, hotkeys

I need to be able to set up a background hotkey event for a WPF application. (by background I mean that the application in question might not necessary be in focus).

I know that with WinForms the proper way of doing it would be to import user32.dll, and use RegisterHotKey, and the catch the appropriate WM_POST message. I'm convinced that there has to be a better solution with WPF, then using user32.dll, but I have been unable to find anything. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think WPF has any built in support for hotkeys, at least I couldn't find any and I used RegisterHotKey directly.

Comment: Agreed, seems like RegisterHotKeys is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

This has an excellent example (see 5.2 "Registering the System Hotkey"):

http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2007/03/15/

It uses the [Managed Windows API](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/), which is a great wrapper around a lot of the legacy api calls.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Commanding infrastructure provided by WPF? You could try assigning some command bindings for you main window and provide some key gestures for it...

Answer (score 0):

You either have to use WinForm like you said or Win32.

I have made a solution in a class (Win32) that you can use directly in a wpf solution.
Just put the class in a separate DLL and any calls to win32 will be transparent to you (and will let you continue to use edit and continue properly). Hope it helps.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne/9330358#9330358)