# WPF MediaCommands while program is running in background

Tags: .net, wpf, routed-commands

I have a program where I've implemented some of the [.NET Media Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mediacommands.aspx) as Routed Commands in my MainWindow like this:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="MediaCommands.TogglePlayPause"
                    Executed="ExecutePlayPause"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteTogglePlayPause" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

This works correctly if the program is currently being used.  However if I switch to a different program and send the TogglePlayPause MediaCommand the command is not fired (CanExecute is never called).

Is there a way to make sure my program always responds to MediaCommands, even if it is running in the background?

FWIW the program Rdio seems to be able do this.  I can have it in the background, send the MediaCommand and the music will play or pause.

Thank You.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633362/proper-way-of-creating-a-background-hotkey-with-wpf-c-preferably-without-usin?lq=1