# .NET Equivalent for Hotkey Control

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, controls, hotkeys

What is the .NET equivalent for the [Hotkey Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775233(VS.85).aspx)?

Comment: For WPF, you can look at my solution at:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne/9330358#9330358][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne/9330358#9330358

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no implementation of HotKey Control in .Net but u can create a Custom control deriving from TextBox. One such implementation available to steal is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/hotkeycontrol.aspx)