# Executing a keyboard command to the OS

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is execute a media key to the operating system. eg: if a user presses a button, it will change the track in itunes or wmp etc.

I am using .Net in C#.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All gathered right here @ stackoverflow:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx

[How can I register a global hot key to say CTRL+SHIFT+(LETTER) using WPF and .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/c-using-wpf-and-net-35-how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftlett)

http://bloggablea.wordpress.com/2007/05/01/global-hotkeys-with-net/

Enjoy it :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to make it appear as though the user pressed one of the media keys on the keyboard?

Use the Windows [`SendInput`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html) function and pass it a `KEYBDINPUT` structure containing, for instance, `VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK`.